# Split long commands in multiple lines through Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, line-continuation

How can I split long commands over multiple lines in a batch file?

Answer (score 1231, accepted):

You can break up long lines with the caret `^` as long as you remember that the caret and the newline following it are completely removed. So, if there should be a space where you're breaking the line, include a space. *([More on that below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21000752/157247))*

Example:

```
copy file1.txt file2.txt
```

would be written as:

```
copy file1.txt^
 file2.txt
```

Comment: You can start the next line without a space if you add a space just before the `^` and after your command text.

Comment: Seems to be limited to just the first two additional lines?

Comment: Worked for me beautifully with a SQL script that executes long SQL queries using sqlcmd.exe . Delayed expansion even allows me to escape the greater-than and less-than chars. Thanks!

Comment: @SebaIllingworth - No, you can always add [SPACE]+[^] and two blank lines to create a total of 2 line-feeds when it's `echo`ed.

Comment: @Andriy M - I hear you.  I don't believe there needs to be a space before or after the last carrot on a line if you are trying to do a line continuation.  More specifically, I believe you have to do it one of two ways:  1) a space before the carrot and the next line need not have a space  OR 2) no space before or after carrot but next line starts with a space.

Comment: For safety **_always_ end with blank line** when using carets, see [Simple carat in batch file consumes all memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466298)

Comment: The description of spaces around the caret in this answer is *really* confused. It's very simple: In the result, the caret and the newline that follows it don't exist. So if there was supposed to be a space there (as in between command parameters), you need to put a space there. I've rewritten this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21000752/157247). I would normally just edit the answer, but it seemed wrong to *completely rewrite* someone else's answer.

Comment: @GavinMiller: *"caret ^ after copy and file1.txt on a new line won't work"* That isn't true. You can split the line anywhere, including in the middle of a word, like `co^␍py ^␍file1 ^␍file2`. I suggest you delete your comment to avoid confusion, especially as this questyion is such a popular one

Comment: @SebaIllingworth - I tried to use ^ to break my own long command to 7 lines and it worked just fine (windows 7). Below, there is an answer that states that there are limitation to the total length of broken command - maybe that was you chokepoint? You could make tests with short generic commands like 'type' to show few files like 1.txt 2.txt etc...

Comment: One gotcha here is that the ^ has to be the last character on the line - i.e. no spaces after.  I was having trouble with this and it turned out I had a bunch of spaces after the caret - not easily visible in the editor I was using.

Comment: Make sure not to put double quotes around your variable, it requires extra wizardry to make it work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643376/how-to-split-double-quoted-line-into-multiple-lines-in-windows-batch-file

Comment: A special character `<>|"&^` at the beginning of a wrapped piece will lose its special meaning due to the continuation caret escaping it.  So starting each wrapped piece with a space seems a safe habit. `the line continuation escapes the first character of the next line` --@dbenham, April 2012.

Answer (score 346):

The rule for the caret is:

A caret at the line end, appends the next line, the first character of the appended line will be escaped.

You can use the caret multiple times, but the complete line must not exceed the maximum line length of ~8192 characters (Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7).

```
echo Test1
echo one ^
two ^
three ^
four^
*
--- Output ---
Test1
one two three four*

echo Test2
echo one & echo two
--- Output ---
Test2
one
two

echo Test3
echo one & ^
echo two
--- Output ---
Test3
one
two

echo Test4
echo one ^
& echo two
--- Output ---
Test4
one & echo two
```

To suppress the escaping of the next character you can use a redirection.

The redirection has to be just before the caret.
But there exist one curiosity with redirection before the caret.

If you place a token at the caret the token is removed.

```
echo Test5
echo one <nul ^
& echo two
--- Output ---
Test5
one
two


echo Test6
echo one <nul ThisTokenIsLost^
& echo two
--- Output ---
Test6
one
two
```

And it is also possible to **embed line feeds** into the string:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set text=This creates ^

a line feed
echo Test7: %text%
echo Test8: !text!
--- Output ---
Test7: This creates
Test8: This creates
a line feed
```

The empty line is important for the success. This works only with delayed expansion, else the rest of the line is ignored after the line feed.

It works, because the caret at the line end ignores the next line feed and escapes the next character, even if the next character is also a line feed (carriage returns are always ignored in this phase).

Comment: The final code block with the line feed example does not display the blank line, even though it is there. (At least it doesn't show up in IE7) Try reformatting using a blockquote instead.

Comment: The question is, do we should support a bad tool that didn't follow the rules (someone call it a browser, but it isn't) or do you should switch to a browser?

Comment: i had double quotes surrounding my values, as in set var="text here ^ " but it does not work.  Remove the double quote and it is fine.

Comment: @jeb, wrote up an example failing cmd script, but then found this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643376/splitting-doublequoted-line-into-multiple-lines-in-windows-batch

Comment: This does not work if the next line starts with a quotation mark: `copy ^[newline]"file1.txt" ^[newline]"file2.txt"` does not work! I had to add a space: `copy ^[newline] "file1.txt" ^[newline] "file2.txt"`.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh That's the expected behaviour, described `...the first character of the appended line will be escaped.` you can use a space or the solution described at `To suppress the escaping of the next character you can use a redirection. ...`

Comment: If you want the pipe symbol `|` (or `&`) at the start of the next line, make sure to **add a space** before it! Otherwise it will be escaped and not work as intended. Detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73930319/3705191

Answer (score 126):

You can break up long lines with the caret (`^`), just remember that the caret and the newline that follows it *are removed entirely* from the command, so if you put it where a space would be required (such as between parameters), be sure to include the space as well (either before the `^`, or at the beginning of the next line — that latter choice may help make it clearer it's a continuation).

⚠ Note: The first character of the next line is escaped. So if it carries any special meaning (like `&` or `|`), that meaning will be lost and it will be interpreted as a pure text character (see last example at bottom).

Examples: *(all tested on Windows XP and Windows 7)*

```
xcopy file1.txt file2.txt
```

can be written as:

```
xcopy^
 file1.txt^
 file2.txt
```

or

```
xcopy ^
file1.txt ^
file2.txt
```

or even

```
xc^
opy ^
file1.txt ^
file2.txt
```

(That last works because there are no spaces betwen the `xc` and the `^`, and no spaces at the beginning of the next line. So when you remove the `^` and the newline, you get...`xcopy`.)

For readability and sanity, it's probably best breaking only between parameters (be sure to include the space).

Be sure that the `^` is **not** the last thing in a batch file, as there [appears to be a major issue with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466298/simple-caret-in-batch-file-consumes-all-memory).

Here's an example of character escaped at the start of the next line:

```
xcopy file1.txt file2.txt ^
& echo copied successfully
```

This will not work because `&` will be escaped and lose its special meaning, thus sending all of "file1.txt file2.txt & echo copied successfully" as parameters to `xcopy`, causing an error (in this example).

To circumvent, **add a space** at the beginning of the next line.

*(This is basically a rewrite of [Wayne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69079/157247) but with the confusion around the caret cleared up. So I've posted it as a CW. I'm not shy about editing answers, but **completely rewriting them** seems inappropriate.)*

Answer (score 26):

Multiple commands can be put in parenthesis and spread over numerous lines; so something like `echo hi && echo hello` can be put like this:

```
( echo hi
  echo hello )
```

Also variables can help:

```
set AFILEPATH="C:\SOME\LONG\PATH\TO\A\FILE"
if exist %AFILEPATH% (
  start "" /b %AFILEPATH% -option C:\PATH\TO\SETTING...
) else (
...
```

Also I noticed with carets (`^`) that the `if` conditionals liked them to follow only if a space was present:

```
if exist ^
```

Comment: The line `cmd1.bat && cmd2.bat` is different from the parens form: execute `cmd2.bat` iff `cmd1.bat` executed successfully (-without setting `%errorcode%`). The latter form executes unconditionally. Somewhat unexpected (at least for me) is that, obviously, you can't use the combination of both + i.e. add `&&` before the line break.

Comment: `( echo <line break here>
  hello )` results in an empty line.

Comment: best and cleanest answer! carets are ugly and problematic in regex

Answer (score 15):

It seems however that splitting in the middle of the values of a for loop doesn't need a caret(and actually trying to use one will be considered a syntax error). For example,

```
for %n in (hello
bye) do echo %n
```

Note that no space is even needed after hello or before bye.

Comment: Of course, this is part of the `for` syntax: the separators of elements in the "for-set" are space, comma, semicolon, equal-sign, TAB character and new-lines.

Comment: But what if `do` part contains multiple/nested `if-else` statements ?

Comment: Then you can simply use parentheses to enclose the statements like

    for %n in (hello bye) do (
        echo %n
        echo %n
    )

Comment: this a possible approach but you first need to store all the items in one line and execute it once.

Answer (score 11):

One thing I did not find when searching for 'how to split a long DOS batch file line' was how to split something containing long quoted text.
In fact it IS covered in the answers above, but is not obvious.  Use Caret to escape them.
e.g.

```
myprog "needs this to be quoted"
```

can be written as:

```
myprog ^"needs this ^
to be quoted^"
```

but beware of starting a line with Caret after ending a line with caret - because it will come out as caret..?:

```
echo ^"^
needs this ^
to be quoted^
^"
```

-> "needs this to be quoted^"

Comment: You don't need to escape the last quote. A caret (or any other special character) at the first column in a new line will be escaped by a multi line caret

Comment: good point! :) ...  I'm using this for splitting VERY long ffmpeg '-vf' arguments, and it's working a treat.

Comment: what if the multiline needs to be quoted, eg  ^"^ ....Get-Volume | Flush-Volume?

Answer (score 8):

Though the carret will be preferable way to do this here's one more approach using macro that constructs a command by the passed arguments:

```
@echo off
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set "{{=setlocal enableDelayedExpansion&for %%a in (" & set "}}="::end::" ) do if "%%~a" neq "::end::" (set command=!command! %%a) else (call !command! & endlocal)"
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

%{{%
    echo
    "command"
    written
    on a
    few lines
%}}%
```

command is easier to read without the carets but using special symbols e.g. brackets,redirection and so on will break it. So you can this for more simpler cases. Though you can still enclose parameters in double quotes

Comment: this is what black magic or Jamaican voodoo looks like.