# How can I echo a newline in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, newline

How can you you insert a newline from your batch file output?

I want to do something like:

```bat
echo hello\nworld
```

Which would output:

```bat
hello
world
```

Comment: Came in useful for me. I had to do echo \n \n | my_app.exe in a script. I did (echo. && echo.) | my_app.exe

Comment: Easy Approach " Code starts :" >  echo hello&echo world , will give u what u need

Comment: You can insert an invisible ascii chr(255) on a separate line which will force a blank new line. Hold down the [alt] key and press 255 on the keypad. this inserts chr(255) which is a blank square. i.e. "*echo (alt+255)*" You can only use the keypad not the numbers at the top of the querty keyboard!

Comment: Just as half of computer repair is plugging it in and turning it on, half of software development is what I call **space engineering**. We _need_ our blank lines just so.

Comment: How About This ? `echo Yes&echo No`

Comment: @jwzumwalt thank you for the alt+255 suggestion, works great on the command line

Comment: printf "\n\n\n"

Comment: Has anyone here offered newline as an external command batchfile? `NEWLINE.bat`. Some of the solutions here don't work properly as-is, in a separate batchfile. For example, some syntax will give `ECHO is off` if called directly from the command-line.

Answer (score 539, accepted):

`echo hello & echo.world`

This means you could define `& echo.` as a constant for a newline `\n`.

Comment: the example doesn't need a period, but you do need one to echo a blank empty line: `echo. && echo hello && echo. && echo world`

Comment: Can you do this with a single echo so it can be redirected to a file?

Comment: @Shahbaz - `$ (echo Hello && echo World) > ./File.txt`

Comment: The period thing in "echo." never stops amazing me. It's so dated, and  still I always forget that the dot must be strictly concatenated with the command name, with no spaces between. There's no error in the post of yours, I'm writing this just as a reminder: "echo ." != "echo." !

Comment: The final answer is missing: $ echo.>>myfile.txt this will add a line break in a file

Comment: Just thought I'd add this.  I wanted to view the system `PATH` variable from the command line, but easily readable.  This post helped me, and I came up with this: `for /f "tokens=*" %i in ("%path%") do set a=%i && set (b=!a:;=^&echo.!)` then `echo %b%` and voila!  Line by line output.

Comment: I have more info! `echo.` makes a new line. `echo` shows the text instead of  `'hello' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer, Single `&` works too: `(echo Hello&echo World) > ./File.txt`

Comment: @mattwilkie, What's the difference between two `&&` instead of one `&`?

Comment: @Pacerier a single ampersand means "do this, then that" while double means "do this, and if no error then do that". Double pipe, `||`, is it's mate, " do this, if failure then do that". See http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, it gets even stranger. Other characters besides dot work too.   SS64 says better syntax is [`echo(`](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) for improved performance (still with no space mind you). Extended discussion of other characters and their merits/flaws at [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=774)

Comment: @mattwilkie, Continue at [the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files#comment8188921_3123194) in the answer below....

Comment: @mattwilkie - technically, "do this, then that" would be using a single semicolon (e.g. `echo hi; echo bye;`).  Using a single ampersand can have the same result, but it would combine the two return values into one collective binary value rather than having two separate, independent return values (it's more complicated than this, but this is the beginning of the basics haha).

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer, this Command/CMD (Dos/Windows) not bash etc. Semicolon is just another character and doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Note that the _space_ between `hello` and the `&` is echoed too! Just remove it to avoid that...

Comment: @quetzalcoatl wow, it's like punctuation matters in programming. Those darn spaces.

Comment: @mattwilkie SS64 recommends [`echo:`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) now.

Answer (score 689):

Use:

```
echo hello
echo:
echo world
```

Comment: Is it possible while providing a string within a single echo statement?

Comment: Why do you need to do it with a single echo statement; where's the harm in having another?

Comment: @Rob, I just came across this problem and none of these work. You need to echo in a single statement in my example. I am generating some tex files from HTML and generating a Makefile by using `echo "Makefile contents (which has \n)" > Makefile` With multiple echos, it wouldn't work

Comment: @Rob, Of course we need a single statement..... How would you pipe the 3 echos to a file then?

Comment: @Rob, can't you just answer Brian R, Bondy's question? He doesn't ask for alternative approaches

Comment: Use `echo;` instead of `echo.`. For some reason, `echo.` will not work in the case that the working directory happens to have a file called `echo` in it already. However, `echo;` works fine.

Comment: Use & (or &&) to do them in a single statement: For example, to put "hello\nworld" in a txt file: `(echo hello & echo world) >> ./test.txt`

Comment: For multi-line output to a file why not just do the following?  `echo line 1 > Makefile` and then `echo line 2 >> Makefile` .  Use of `>>` causes the output to be appended to the file, which is precisely the behavior you need for this case.

Comment: `echo:` is recommended by [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html).

Comment: If anybody ever wondered how this trick works, here is how. `^` or `:` characters in `echo` command can be used to escape command characters `like & < > | ON OFF`, so by using `:` we are basically escaping the newline! Seems very hacky, but it works! It also works with text files like this `echo:>>foo.txt`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get an extra blank line. I just want a line return.

Answer (score 161):

Here you go, create a .bat file with the following in it :

```
@echo off
REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
REM Example Usage:
echo There should be a newline%NL%inserted here.

echo.
pause
```

You should see output like the following:

```
There should be a newline
inserted here.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

You only need the code between the REM statements, obviously.

Comment: Very impressive, could you take time to explain how the line 

set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%


works? I can't quite get my head round it

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work when passing the `echo`ed string to another program.

Comment: @andy methinks a +8 comment warrants a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379619/explain-how-dos-batch-newline-variable-hack-works

Comment: This is a wonderful example to show that cmd.exe and Windows batch files are totally insane!

Comment: NOTE TO SELF: The line "set NLM=^" **must** have nothing after the CARET and **must** have 2 blank lines after it.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use it in a variable. For example, `set z=foo%NL%bar & echo %z%` will not give the expected results, it will only print `foo`.

Comment: See my answer for a simpler method.  `set nl=^&echo.`, then just `echo hello %nl% world` yields the same effect.

Comment: I'm getting "There should be a newlineinserted here."

Comment: @Synetech You can indeed put a linebreak in a variable, using the first form.  Try this out: `set A=first line^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%second line` then `echo %A%`

Comment: @rkagerer, it works. Nice!  (Too bad the command-line's escaping methods are so insane. :-\)

Comment: It will work for SET variables if you use DelayedExpansion and !! instead of %%. For example, `set ErrMsg=!NL!Error Title1!NL!Description!NL!Summary!NL!`

Comment: `echo.` is the trick!

Answer (score 121):

There is a standard feature `echo:` in cmd/bat-files to write blank line, which emulates a new line in your cmd-output:

```bash
@echo off
echo line1
echo:
echo line2
```

or

```bash
@echo line1 & echo: & echo line2
```

Output of cited above cmd-file:

```
line1

line2
```

Comment: In fact, any UNUSED special char should work. I always encourage the use of / because the slash is the standard char for command options. Also, I always criticize the use of the dot that somebody in Microsoft unfortunately choose because the command: echo.com give different results depending on the version of MS-DOS/Windows Batch command processor.

Comment: The only version that always works is `echo(`. It looks like it could cause problems, but it actually works perfectly. All other forms have at least one situation where the command will not perform as desired.

Comment: @Aacini could you find some reference for this? I tested and it works which is fascinating but there must exist some designer memo, specification or at least manual that tells this story.

Comment: @dbenham this is even more fascinating. do you know about examples or explanation about the situations you speak of? also, do you know about any designer story, memo, specification or manual that describes this feature of the dos and cmd command line?

Comment: @naxa - Nothing official, just collective knowledge derived by a few batch hackers. The goal is to have syntax that can be used to ECHO any value, including nothing, and never have to worry about getting anything other than what is expected. The best summary I know of is at http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4554#p4554. It kind of leaves you hanging, but no one has ever come up with a scenario where `ECHO(` fails.

Comment: @dbenham, The claim that `echo(` is the only version which works is incorrect. The author rules against `.`, `+`, `[`, and `]`, but there is still "`echo=`", "`echo,`", "`echo\ `", "`echo/ `" and "`echo:`" which he didn't address at all.

Comment: @Aacini, Why not `echo=`? Using `/` is misleading because `/` already has a meaning in cmd (used for representing flags).

Comment: @Pacerier: try `echo=/?` and `echo,/?` and you will see that both fails (because they do _not_ show "/?"). From the remaining three, `echo\/?` looks like an "escape" in other languages, and `echo:/?` may be mistaken for a label or drive. The form that looks "more standard" is `echo//?` _precisely_ because `/` is used for command options!

Comment: @Pacerier - there are examples of failure for each of those suggestions. Carefully read http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4554#p4554.

Comment: @Pacerier there is enough _echo_  going on here for a standalone question. Perhaps something along the lines of "what characters can immediately follow `echo`, and what are their effects?"

Comment: Can confirm `echo(` seems arbitrarily safe, even in deeply nested FOR loops which can be notorious for special-character weirdness handling.

Comment: @dbenham when I use `echo(` it is not creating a newline, but rather this `ഠ嘊攀爀猀椀漀渀                    ഀ਀　㤀㘀䌀㄀　　　　　㐀　㔀䘀　　　㔀㄀㘀㘀　㄀㠀　  ഀ਀`.

Comment: @CardinalSystem Was this with a Chinese Windows? Or on a PC fabricated in China? Or perhaps hacked by a Samurai? :)

Answer (score 87):

Like the answer of Ken, but with the use of the delayed expansion.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set \n=^
%=Do not remove this line=%
)

echo Line1!\n!Line2
echo Works also with quotes "!\n!line2"
```

First a single linefeed character is created and assigned to the \n-variable.
This works as the caret at the line end tries to escape the next character, but if this is a Linefeed it is ignored and the next character is read and escaped (even if this is also a linefeed).
Then you need a third linefeed to end the current instruction, else the third line would be appended to the LF-variable.
Even batch files have line endings with CR/LF only the LF are important, as the CR's are removed in this phase of the parser.

The advantage of using the delayed expansion is, that there is no special character handling at all.
`echo Line1%LF%Line2` would fail, as the parser stops parsing at single linefeeds.

More explanations are at
[SO:Long commands split over multiple lines in Vista/DOS batch (.bat) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/long-commands-split-over-multiple-lines-in-vista-dos-batch-bat-file/4455750#4455750)
[SO:How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)

**Edit: Avoid `echo.`**

This doesn't answer the question, as the question was about single `echo` that can output multiple lines.

But despite the other answers who suggests the use of `echo.` to create a new line, it should be noted that `echo.` is the worst, as it's very slow and it can completly fail, as cmd.exe searches for a file named `ECHO` and try to start it.

For printing just an empty line, you could use one of

```
echo,
echo;
echo(
echo/
echo+
echo=
```

But the use of `echo.`, `echo\` or `echo:` should be avoided, as they can be really slow, depending of the location where the script will be executed, like a network drive.

Comment: If you will be passing the string with newlines as a parameter to a batch subroutine, e.g. `call :pause line1!\n!line2`, start the subroutine with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and end it with `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion` to keep the newlines from being interpreted prematurely.

Comment: +1 for the cast of characters `echo,` `echo;` `echo(` `echo/` `echo+` `echo=` and the rogues gallery `echo.` ``echo\``  `echo:`. Now if you were to explain why in holy heck these work, I'd owe you a free beer.

Comment: Can you put the newline into a NEWLINE.bat script by itself?

Comment: @johnywhy Yes, move the code into the `newline.bat` probably with an  `echo(!\n!`

Comment: @jeb You're saying i have to use an open-paren when i use it from a .bat file? Where does the close-paren go? `echo(!\n!`  My intention is to have call an external setup_newline.bat at the top of every batch file which wants to use your method. Or, even better, just put `newline` where ever i need a newline, and have that `newline` call `newline.bat` which returns `!\n!`

Comment: @johnywhy Better ask a new question, the comments are a bit small for longer descriptions

Comment: @jeb Thx, i might! Plz consider adding this to your answer here.

Comment: This. Awesome sauce. Elegant. Effective.

Answer (score 46):

`echo.` Enough said.

If you need it in a single line, use the `&`. For example,

```
echo Line 1 & echo. & echo line 3
```

would output as:

```
Line 1

line 3
```

**Now, say you want something a bit fancier, ...**

```
set n=^&echo.
echo hello %n% world
```

Outputs

```
hello
world
```

Then just throw in a `%n%` whenever you want a new line in an echo statement.  This is more close to your `\n` used in various languages.

**Breakdown**

`set n=` sets the variable `n` equal to:

`^` Nulls out the next symbol to follow:

`&` Means to do another command on the same line.  We don't care about errorlevel(its an echo statement for crying out loud), so no `&&` is needed.

`echo.` Continues the echo statement.

All of this works because you can actually create variables that are code, and use them inside of other commands.  It is sort of like a ghetto function, since batch is not exactly the most advanced of shell scripting languages.  This only works because batch's poor usage of variables, not designating between ints, chars, floats, strings, etc naturally.

If you are crafty, you could get this to work with other things.  For example, using it to echo a tab

```
set t=^&echo.     ::there are spaces up to the double colon
```

Comment: **Do not** use `echo.` as it first attempts to find a file by that name. Use other punctuation, such as `echo,`

Comment: Fails with `echo %n%hello%n%world` → `echo   & echo:hello & echo:world`, of course.

Answer (score 19):

When echoing something to redirect to a file, multiple echo commands will not work. I think maybe the ">>" redirector is a good choice:

```
echo hello > temp
echo world >> temp
```

Comment: The first example, using ">", will create a new file, the second one, using ">>", will append to an existing file (or create it if it doesn't already exist).

Comment: `(echo hello && echo world) > temp` mentioned by Nathan J. Brauer in a comment to the (current) accepted answer works.

Answer (score 18):

If you need to put results to a file, you can use:

```
(echo a & echo: & echo b) > file_containing_multiple_lines.txt
```

Answer (score 14):

Just like Grimtron suggests - here is a quick example to define it:

```
@echo off
set newline=^& echo.
echo hello %newline%world
```

#### Output

```
C:\>test.bat
hello
world
```

Comment: It will actually echo an additional newline after "world"

Comment: @blue the trailing newline seems to be function of the batch file itself. If you repeat the `echo hello %newline%world` line there are no spaces between.

Comment: `echo "Hello %newline% world"` fails as it is inside of quotes. Because it isn't a _real_ newline.

Comment: i see this everywhere and it's misleading/confusing, and of course, horribly inefficient compared to the real newline version.

Comment: @HaxAddict1337 Which is the "real newline version"?

Comment: Fails with `echo %newline%hello%newline%world` → `echo   & echo:hello & echo:world`, of course.

Answer (score 9):

You can also do like this,

```
(for %i in (a b "c d") do @echo %~i)
```

The output will be,

```
a
b
c d
```

Note that when this is put in a batch file, '%' shall be doubled.

```
(for %%i in (a b "c d") do @echo %%~i)
```

Comment: This solution also works if you want to echo an ampersand & instead of a newline.

Comment: i think i found a bug: the `*` char

Comment: This is an unnecessarily complicated `echo a & echo b & echo c d` and doesn't answer the question with `echo a sentence that contains\na newline identifier in it`. Of course, one could write `for %%i in ("a sentence that contains" "a newline in it") do @echo %%~i`, but really?

Answer (score 8):

If anybody comes here because they are looking to echo a blank line from a MINGW make makefile, I used

`@cmd /c echo.`

simply using `echo.` causes the dreaded `process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, echo., ...) failed.` error message.

I hope this helps at least one other person out there :)

Comment: Not sure if sarcasm or not :P

Comment: Find out by looking in your inbox :D

Answer (score 6):

To `echo` a newline, add a dot `.` right after the `echo`:

```
echo.
```

Comment: Adding an answer to a 15 years old question should contain anything new, but your answer is already given multiple times here before. Btw. `echo.` isn't a good answer, because it has drawbacks

Answer (score 4):

After a sleepless night and after reading all answers herein, after reading a lot of [SS64 > CMD](https://ss64.com/nt/) and after a lot of try & error I found:

## The (almost) Ultimate Solution

### TL;DR

... for early adopters.

| Important! |
| --- |
| **Use a text editor for C&P that supports Unicode, e.g. Notepad++!** |

#### Set Newline Environment Variable ...

##### ... in the Current CMD Session

| Important! |
| --- |
| **Do *not* edit anything between '`=`' and '`^`'!** (There's a character in between though you don't see it. Neither here nor in edit mode. C&P works here.) |

```bash
:: Sets newline variables in the current CMD session
set \n=​^&echo(
set nl=​^&echo(
```

##### ... for the Current User

| Important! |
| --- |
| **Do *not* edit anything between (the second) '`␣`' and '`^`'!** (There's a character in between though you don't see it. Neither here nor in edit mode. C&P works here.) |

```bash
:: Sets newline variables for the current user [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment]
setx \n ​^&echo(
setx nl ​^&echo(
```

##### ... for the Local Machine

| Important! |
| --- |
| **Do *not* edit anything between (the second) '`␣`' and '`^`'!** (There's a character in between though you don't see it. Neither here nor in edit mode. C&P works here.) |

```bash
:: Sets newline variables for the local machine [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment]
setx \n ​^&echo( /m 
setx nl ​^&echo( /m
```

### Why just almost?

It does not work with double-quotes that are *not paired* (opened and closed) in the same *printed line*, except if the only unpaired double-quote is the last character of the text, e.g.:

- works: `""echo %\n%...after "newline". Before "newline"...%\n%...after "newline"` (paired in each *printed line*)
- works: `echo %\n%...after newline. Before newline...%\n%...after newline"` (the only unpaired double-quote is the last character)
- doesn't work: `echo "%\n%...after newline. Before newline...%\n%...after newline"` (double-quotes are *not paired* in the same *printed line*)

  Workaround for completely double-quoted texts (inspired by [*Windows batch: echo without new line*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7105433/1744774)):

  ```bash
  set BEGIN_QUOTE=echo ^| set /p !="""
  ...
  %BEGIN_QUOTE%
  echo %\n%...after newline. Before newline...%\n%...after newline"
  ```

It works with completely single-quoted texts like:

```bash
echo '%\n%...after newline. Before newline...%\n%...after newline'
```

##### Added value: Escape Character

| Note |
| --- |
| There's a character after the '`=`' but you don't see it here but in edit mode. C&P works here. |

```bash
:: Escape character - useful for color codes when 'echo'ing
:: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#text-formatting
set ESC=
```

For the colors see also https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SkGq.jpg and https://gist.github.com/gerib/f2562474e7ca0d3cda600366ee4b8a45.

##### 2nd added value: Getting Unicode characters easily

A great page for getting 87,461 Unicode characters (AToW) by keyword(s): https://www.amp-what.com/.

## The Reasons

- The version in [Ken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/269819/1744774) works apparently (I didn't try it), but is somehow...well...you see:

  ```bash
  set NLM=^


  set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
  ```
- The version derived from [user2605194](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24792710/1744774)'s and [user287293](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2388384/1744774)'s answer (without anything between '`=`' and '`^`'):

  ```bash
  set nl=^&echo(
  set \n=^&echo(
  ```

  works partly but fails with the variable at the beginning of the line to be `echo`ed:

  ```bash
  > echo %\n%Hello%\n%World!
  echo   & echo(Hello & echo(World!
  echo is ON.
  Hello
  World
  ```

  due to the blank argument to the first `echo`.
- All others are more or less invoking three `echo`s explicitely.
- I like short one-liners.

## The Story Behind

To prevent `set \n=^&echo:` suggested in answers herein echoing blank (and such printing its status) I first remembered the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> user from the times when Novell was a widely used network and code pages like [437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) and [850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) were used. But 0d255/0xFF is [›Ÿ‹ (Latin Small Letter Y with diaeresis)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)) in Unicode nowadays.

Then I remembered that there are [more spaces](https://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/space) in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) than the ordinary 0d32/0x20 but all of them are considered whitespaces and lead to the same behaviour as ›␣‹.

But there are even more: the *zero width spaces* and *joiners* which are not considered as whitespaces. The problem with them is, that you cannot C&P them since with their zero width there's nothing to select. So, I copied one that is close to one of them, the *hair space* (U+200A) which is right before the *zero width space* (U+200B) into Notepad++, opened its Hex-Editor plugin, found its bit representation `E2 80 8A` and changed it to `E2 80 8B`. Success! I had a non-whitespace character that's not visible in my `\n` environment variable.

Comment: on standard codepage `437` this line: `echo Hello%\n%world` will echo `HelloΓÇï` <newline> `World`  but works when doing `chcp 65001`

Comment: @Gerhard No wonder, CP 437 is no Unicode codepage. I saw the same on Windows 7. Which standard? Windows 7 and prior to that? Unicode is 30(!) years old now. I think it can, even should be considered as standard now.

Comment: The code page in my region on a newly installed windows 10 pro system is 437.

Comment: @Gerhard Yes, MS ignored Unicode in their OSs for decades. Since Win 8 I work with them only if I must.

Comment: `set \n=​^&echo:`  is only a weak hack, it isn't a newline definition. Or try `set multiline=Line1%\n%Line2` and then `echo ### !multiline!`. The answer from Ken should be used or the delayed expansion variant of it.

Answer (score 3):

Ken and Jeb solutions works well.

But the new lines are generated with only an LF character and I need CRLF characters (Windows version).

To this, at the end of the script, I have converted LF to CRLF.

Example:

```
TYPE file.txt | FIND "" /V > file_win.txt
del file.txt
rename file_win.txt file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

If one needs to use famous \n in string literals that can be passed to a variable, may write a code like in the *Hello.bat* script below:

```
@echo off
set input=%1
if defined input (
    set answer=Hi!\nWhy did you call me a %input%?
) else (
    set answer=Hi!\nHow are you?\nWe are friends, you know?\nYou can call me by name.
)

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set newline=^


rem Two empty lines above are essential
echo %answer:\n=!newline!%
```

This way multiline output may by prepared in one place, even in other scritpt or external file, and printed in another.

The line break is held in *newline* variable. Its value must be substituted **after** the *echo* line is expanded so I use *setlocal enableDelayedExpansion* to enable exclamation signs which expand variables on execution. And the execution substitutes *\n* with *newline* contents (look for syntax at *help set*). We could of course use *!newline!* while setting the *answer* but *\n* is more convenient. It may be passed from outside (try *Hello R2\nD2*), where nobody knows the name of variable holding the line break (Yes, *Hello C3!newline!P0* works the same way).

Above example may be refined to a subroutine or standalone batch, used like `call:mlecho Hi\nI'm your comuter`:

```
:mlecho
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set text=%*
set nl=^


echo %text:\n=!nl!%
goto:eof
```

Please note, that additional backslash won't prevent the script from parsing \n substring.

Comment: You are essentially doing the same thing as Jeb's answer above.

Comment: Answers I read above were very helpful but I needed to call a script od subroutine which will parse \n so I'd avoid implementing the trick everywhere. This needed to refine a solution and I shared this refinement. Hope it didn't harm any animal.

Comment: This answer is useful, but since exclamation marks are interpreted, how can your argument display a litteral exclamation mark? I tried escaping them by prefixing one or two carets, but it did not work.

Comment: @FlorentAngly, try this:

`set ex=!`

`setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`

`echo shout!ex!`

Answer (score 2):

To start a new line in batch, all you have to do is add "echo[", like so:

```
echo Hi!
echo[
echo Hello!
```

Comment: It's slow and it fails when a file exists with the name `echo[.bat`

Comment: What? It should work instantly, and also just delete the echo[.bat file.

Comment: It is pretty much the exact same thing as echo. syntax.

Comment: Yes and `echo.` is a bad solution, too.

Comment: As can be seen in previous answers, this will try to locate a file on the path first, which causes it to be so slow. Same is true for `echo.`. Expecting users of your script to delete files on their system just because your script needs a newline doesn't sound like good design to me.

Answer (score 2):

why not use substring/replace space to `echo;`?

```
set "_line=hello world"
echo\%_line: =&echo;%
```

- Results:

```
hello
world
```

- Or, replace \n to `echo;`

```
set "_line=hello\nworld"
echo\%_line:\n=&echo;%
```

Comment: While this may work (I didn't test it) it's rather inconvenient to assign your (potentially many) texts to an env var and perform a string replacement every time.

Comment: @GeroldBroser 
ok, how about testing and seeing what can be commented if it doesn't work?

Comment: @GeroldBroser About what is and is not inconvenient. This depends on each one and their needs, capacity and knowledge, I can assign variations, substitutions,
 and several substrings in many env var without necessarily writing each one of them.

Comment: why hasn't anyone commented this before? 
Which answer does not bring you equal concerns?

Answer (score 2):

For windows 10 with [virtual terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) there exists the means control the cursor position to a high degree.

To define the escape sequence 0x1b, the following can be used:

```bat
@Echo off
 For /f %%a in ('echo prompt $E^| cmd')Do set \E=%%a
```

To output a single newline Between Strings:

```bat
<nul set /p "=Hello%\E%[EWorld"
```

To output `n` newlines where `n` is replaced with an integer:

```bat
<nul set /p "=%\E%[nE"
```

Many

Comment: See [my comment to @Vopel's answer herein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-i-echo-a-newline-in-a-batch-file/69789865#comment123950560_69789865) with the resume that `ESC [ <n> E` (Cursor Next Line – Cursor down <n> lines from current position) only works unless you haven't reached the bottom of the console window.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that all solutions that use cursor positioning according to [*Console Virtual Terminal Sequences, Cursor Positioning*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#cursor-positioning) with:

| Sequence | Code | Description | Behaviour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ESC [ <n> E | CNL | Cursor Next Line | Cursor down <n> lines from current position |

only work ***as long as the bottom of the console window is not reached***.

At the bottom there is no space left to move the cursor down so it just moves left (with the `CR` of `CRLF`) and the line printed before is overwritten from its beginning.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, no delayed expansion necessary:

```
@echo off
(
echo ^<html^> 
echo ^<body^>
echo Hello
echo ^</body^>
echo ^</html^>
)
pause
```

It writes output like this:

```
<html>
<body>
Hello
</body>
</html>
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: -1 `echo asdf >myfile.txt` will produce the exact same results.  `echo` appends a newline to the end of the string.

Comment: Great answer, being the only person who recognized the value of using the parenthesis for new lines.   I believe this is how the makers of DOS intended you to do it.

Answer (score 1):

14 years later I recommend to use Powershell instead.

You can even most probably just change the file ending from `.bat` to `.ps1` and have it working.

Then, you can use

```
echo "Hello`nWorld"

# or even

echo Hello`nWorld
```

Tested on Win10.

You can also do Windows-type newlines with `` echo "Hello`r`nWorld" ``.

Source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-new-lines-with-powershell/, it says "Use the `n character".

---

A lot of confusion within the other answers and comments was due to `echo` being available on Windows *and* Linux.
For linux, you can simply use `echo "Hello\nWorld"` to get the same result on most distros.

But still, it's recommended to use `printf` in linux scripts.

Comment: It makes no sense to switch the language to solve a minor problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@echo` ( @echo + [space] + [insecable space] )

Note: The insecable space can be obtained with Alt+0160

Hope it helps :)

[edit] Hmm you're right, I needed it in a Makefile, it works perfectly in there. I guess my answer is not adapted for batch files... My bad.

Comment: I got `ECHO ist eingeschaltet (ON).` not an empty line, tried at the cmd-prompt

Comment: That’s a non-breaking space, not a newline.

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
set nl=.
echo hello
echo%nl%
REM without space ^^^
echo World
```

Result:

```
hello
world
```

Comment: Where is the difference to [this 13 years old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/132804/463115)? Your answer is complex without necessity. And like the other *solution*, it doesn't answer the question how to do it with a single echo

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, this won't work in console because it'll simulate an escape key and clear the line.

Using this code, replace `<ESC>` with the 0x1b escape character or use [this Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/xLWKTQZQ):

```
:: Replace <ESC> with the 0x1b escape character or copy from this Pastebin:
:: https://pastebin.com/xLWKTQZQ

echo Hello<ESC>[Eworld!

:: OR

set "\n=<ESC>[E"
echo Hello%\n%world!
```

Comment: This works as long as your command line doesn't reach the bottom of the console window! Then just `world!` is displayed since at the bottom there is no space left to move the cursor down so it just moves left (with the `CR` of `CRLF`) and overwrites `Hello `. Proof: With `echo Hello my%\n%world!` `world!my` is displayed. Anyway, for reference: [_Console Virtual Terminal Sequences_, _Cursor Positioning_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#cursor-positioning).

Comment: Damn, you're right. That's disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a variant to Ken's answer, that shows setting values for environment variables with new lines in them.

We use this method to append error conditions to a string in a VAR, then at the end of all the error checking output to a file as a summary of all the errors.

This is not complete code, just an example.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: the two blank lines are required!
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
:: Example Usage:

Set ErrMsg=Start Reporting:
:: some logic here finds an error condition and appends the error report
set ErrMsg=!ErrMsg!!NL!Error Title1!NL!Description!NL!Summary!NL!

:: some logic here finds another error condition and appends the error report
set ErrMsg=!ErrMsg!!NL!Error Title2!NL!Description!NL!Summary!NL!

:: some logic here finds another error condition and appends the error report
set ErrMsg=!ErrMsg!!NL!Error Title3!NL!Description!NL!Summary!NL!

echo %ErrMsg%
pause
echo %ErrMsg% > MyLogFile.log
```

Log and Screen output look like this...

[image: Log output of the script]

[image: Screen output of the script]

Comment: If you use delayed expansion, I can't see any reason to still use percent expansion with line feeds. With delayed expansion you only need a simple definition for the NL and the echo of variables is simple, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
printf "hello\nworld"
```

Output:

```
hello
world
```

Comment: `printf` is not a valid cmd/batch command.

Comment: It is valid for me !!

Comment: printf works on linux, but the question got the Windows tag.

Answer (score 0):

To write this to a file, the only good option I found is. Unfortunately I had difficulties to get this in a if (in case you get troubles as well, of course I used `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`)

```bash
set text=hello\nworld
set "text=%text:\n= & echo %"
(echo %text%) > file.txt
cat file.txt
```