# How to create empty text file from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

Can somebody remember what was the command to create an empty file in MSDOS using BAT file?

Comment: Also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702762, "How to create an empty file at the command line?".

Comment: You aren't confusing DOS and `cmd.exe`, are you?

Comment: READ ME: `Set-Content "your_file.txt" .gitignore -Encoding utf8` this is case-sensitive and forces utf8 encoding!  (I also posted this as an answer).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create an empty file at the command line in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702762/how-can-i-create-an-empty-file-at-the-command-line-in-windows)

Answer (score 256, accepted):

```
echo. 2>EmptyFile.txt
```

---

This redirects output stream 2 (`stderr`) to a file. The command `echo` doesn't output anything to `stderr`, so the file becomes empty.

Plain `echo` would work too, but `echo.` is better because it doesn't print the useless and potentially confusing message `ECHO is on.`

Comment: This echoes a newline to stdout, though... my answer doesn't.

Comment: That's a fairly tangential concern, I think. Not really part of the problem.

Comment: Sometimes it's relevant; I used to have touch lying around until I got the idea of just copying NUL (or type NUL>file) for the purpose of getting 0-byte files. :-)

Comment: To merge ephemient's answer and this one, you could do: "echo. >NUL 2>EmptyFile.txt" to achieve the same results without outputting a newline

Comment: Why is `.` in `echo.`

Comment: @Reegan If you used `echo 2` without the `.`, the console would read "ECHO is off."  Using `echo. 2` effectively silences console output by only displaying a newline.

Comment: Sorry @ephemient. I didn't see your answer before the comment editing time limit ran out. I should have given you props in my first comment. I'll upvote your answer to make amends. ;^J

Comment: Sorry for the downvote--I was in too much of a hurry. SO won't let me undo it. I'll come back later and try again. I still don't like your answer, though--the new line to stdout is annoying. Anyway, there are better solutions.

Comment: it would be great if you could explain more in your answers or at least give a reference

Comment: Can you change the default encoding?

Comment: it seems that `echo >empty.txt ` works too. what's the difference?

Comment: @DavidH.J.: try it and `type empty.txt` - it isn't empty. (an `empty file` is a file without content - zero bytes length)

Answer (score 407):

```
copy NUL EmptyFile.txt
```

DOS has a few special files (devices, actually) that exist in every directory, `NUL` being the equivalent of UNIX's `/dev/null`: it's a magic file that's always empty and throws away anything you write to it.  Here's a [list](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia_term/0,2542,t=DOS+device+names&i=41766,00.asp) of some others; `CON` is occasionally useful as well.

To avoid having any output at all, you can use

```
copy /y NUL EmptyFile.txt >NUL
```

`/y` prevents `copy` from asking a question you can't see when output goes to `NUL`.

Comment: +1 - the question does state an *empty* file, so the accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: DannySmurf's solution actually does create an empty file -- a newline goes to stdout, nothing goes to stderr (directed into the new file).  But thanks for the +1 anyways

Comment: type nul > EmptyFile.txt is shortest solution. Still your answer is better then accepted solution, cause your file will be really empty. +1

Comment: Warning: yes the question was on how to create an empty file, however usually you want to "make sure the file exists". When using the `copy /Y NUL` command it might erase existing content. If you are used to Unix' `touch` command, this might not at all be what you expect .)  Using `type NUL >> emptyfile.txt` is safer in this regard.

Comment: I couldn't find any information on `CON`, aside from that linked in this answer. Could someone share some light reading?

Comment: @Sinjai `CON` is the console, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#DOS,_TOS,_OS/2,_and_Windows

Comment: @ephemient Awesome, do you have anything on practical uses?

Comment: @Sinjai `copy /y CON file.txt` lets you type several lines, ending with ^Z, to create a file without opening an editor. If a command normally prints to a file, using `CON` will cause its output to go to the screen. Stuff like that.

Comment: For me, win10, this causes syntax-error? So filepath is not valid?

Answer (score 204):

```
type NUL > EmptyFile.txt
```

After reading the previous two posts, this blend of the two is what I came up with. It seems a little cleaner. There is no need to worry about redirecting the "1 file(s) copied." message to `NUL`, like the previous post does, and it looks nice next to the `ECHO OutputLineFromLoop >> Emptyfile.txt` that will usually follow in a batch file.

Comment: +1 this is the natural one that first comes to mind, not the contrivances with stderr etc.

Comment: You are correct. This method avoides the /y flag on the copy command.

Comment: Short and easy. A few other solutions here do not create a new file of zero bytes!

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer.  About as clean and simple as it gets.

Answer (score 82):

Techniques I gathered from other answers:

**Makes a 0 byte file** a very clear, backward-compatible way:

```
type nul >EmptyFile.txt
```

idea via: [anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295214/611007), [Danny Backett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/how-to-create-empty-text-file-from-a-batch-file#comment19853904_1330484), possibly others, myself inspired by [JdeBP's work](https://superuser.com/users/38062/jdebp)

**A 0 byte file another way**, it's backward-compatible-looking:

```
REM. >EmptyFile.txt
```

idea via: [Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2620900/611007)

**A 0 byte file 3rd way** backward-compatible-looking, too:

```
echo. 2>EmptyFile.txt
```

idea via: [TheSmurf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/210209/611007)

**A 0 byte file the systematic way** [probably](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457122.aspx) available since Windows 2000:

```
fsutil file createnew EmptyFile.txt 0
```

idea via: [Emm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5507221/611007)

**A 0 bytes file overwriting readonly files**

```
ATTRIB -R filename.ext>NUL
(CD.>filename.ext)2>NUL
```

idea via: [copyitright](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458324/611007)

**A single newline** (2 bytes: `0x0D 0x0A` in [hex notation](http://wiki.osdev.org/Hexadecimal_Notation), alternatively written as `\r\n`):

```
echo.>AlmostEmptyFile.txt
```

Note: *no* space between `echo`, `.` and `>`.

idea via: [How can you echo a newline in batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files)

---

**edit** It seems that *any invalid* command *redirected* to a file would create an empty file. heh, a feature!
compatibility: uknown

```
TheInvisibleFeature <nul >EmptyFile.txt
```

**A 0 bytes file: invalid command/ with a random name** (compatibility: uknown):

```
%RANDOM%-%TIME:~6,5% <nul >EmptyFile.txt
```

via: great [source](http://unserializableone.blogspot.hu/2009/04/create-unique-temp-filename-with-batch.html) for random by Hung Huynh

**edit 2** Andriy M [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/how-to-create-empty-text-file-from-a-batch-file/23158286?noredirect=1#comment35653129_23158286) the probably most amusing/provoking way to achieve this via invalid command

**A 0 bytes file: invalid command/ the funky way** (compatibility: unknown)

```
*>EmptyFile.txt
```

idea via: [Andriy M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297408/andriy-m)

**A 0 bytes file 4th-coming way**:

```
break > file.txt
```

idea via: [foxidrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/how-to-create-empty-text-file-from-a-batch-file/24822936#24822936) thanks to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/how-to-create-empty-text-file-from-a-batch-file/23158286?noredirect=1#comment43905374_23158286) of [Double Gras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289317/double-gras)!

Comment: It's `type nul ...`, not `type <nul ...`, actually.

Comment: @AndriyM thanks you're right I made the edit! Didn't notice because interestingly enough it works with the wrong one. which may mean that any invalid command redirected to a filename would create an empty file! just tried with `NonExistentCommand <nul >EmptyFile.txt` and it worked

Comment: since it would be unsafe to rely on a hardcoded command name expecting it to be "invalid", I added a randomized command name option

Comment: That's interesting. As for random command name generation, that might be unnecessary, you could just use `*>EmptyFile.txt` or anything where the "command" contains a character highly unlikely to be part of the name. I admit, though, that there's always a tiny risk it becomes a valid command in the future.

Comment: @AndriyM now *thats* fun. You could even make it *self-documenting* with `?>EmptyFile.txt` ;) - `?` as in *"what?!?!"*. Well, you could actually do `?!?!>EmptyFile.txt` or `?????>EmptyFile.txt`, to make it clear. :P

Comment: Yet another one: [`break > file.txt`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/how-to-create-empty-text-file-from-a-batch-file/24822936#24822936), props [foxidrive](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2299431/foxidrive)

Comment: And most of the commands can be used with `>>` if you need "must exist but should not be truncated if exist" (like Unix `touch` does)

Answer (score 27):

REM. > empty.file

Comment: I'm stuck on Windows CE, and this is the only answer that creates and empty file! The other approaches either add a blank line or simply don't work...

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that if there is a file called REM in the current directory, and you type `REM.`, cmd will respond with "'rem.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @DodgyCodeException, using `rem/` instead of `rem.` solves that problem...

Comment: @aschipfl thanks, that's interesting. It's also interesting how this answer from 2010 has comments spaced from each other by several years. A slowwwww conversation!

Answer (score 11):

If there's a possibility that the to be written file already exists and is read only, use the following code:

```
ATTRIB -R filename.ext
CD .>filename.ext
```

If no file exists, simply do:

```
CD .>filename.ext
```

(updated/changed code according to DodgyCodeException's comment)

To supress any errors that may arise:

```
ATTRIB -R filename.ext>NUL
(CD .>filename.ext)2>NUL
```

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that if there is a file called `CD` (no extension) in the current directory, and you type `CD.`, cmd will respond with "'CD.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." If you instead type `CD .` (with a space before the dot) it will work.

Answer (score 9):

One more to add to the books - short and sweet to type.

```
break>file.txt
break>"file with spaces in name.txt"
```

Comment: I guess we woyld skip the quotes

Comment: @NamGVU The quotes are used in the target filename, if you choose to use long filename elements such as space or & etc.  They are not part of the file contents.

Comment: Yeah I agree ^^ Permission to update yours as discussed.

Comment: @NamGVU The quotes are able to be left in place with or without a long filename.  I guess if it's typed from the command line with a short filename, then you wouldn't want unnecessary typing.

Comment: I suggest removing the second line from this answer. IMO this is the best answer on the question so far, but the second line doesn't really add value unless the person trying to use it doesn't know the basics of white-space handling for command-line.

Comment: best answer, as is, although I would love background on break statement since I am reverse engineering an old bat file and all I found was "how to pause" when looking for the meaning of this statement. probably got there from an answer like this.

Answer (score 7):

```
fsutil file createnew file.cmd 0
```

Comment: The FSUTIL utility requires that you have administrative privileges.

Comment: fsutil is not a standard utility in MS-DOS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `TYPE` command instead of `COPY`.  Try this:

```
TYPE File1.txt>File2.txt
```

Where `File1.txt` is empty.

Comment: You can also do `type NUL>File2.txt`

Comment: BTW, how to get File1.txt?

Answer (score 2):

There are infinite approaches.

Commands that output nothing:

```
break
cls
color
goto
pushd
popd
prompt
title
```

Weird Commands:

```
CD.
REM.
@echo off
cmd /c
START >FILE
```

The outdated `print` command produces a blank file:

```
print /d:EMPTY_TEXT_FILE nul
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `SET` to create a null `byte` file as follows

```
set x=x > EmptyFile.txt
```

Or if you don't want to create an extra variable reassign an existing variable like

```
set PROMPT=%PROMPT% > EmptyFile.txt
```

or like this:

```
set "PROMPT=%PROMPT%" > EmptyFile.txt
```

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way is:

`echo. > Filename.txt`

Comment: This will create a file with a space character followed by a carriage return character followed by a new line character – **not** an empty file.

Comment: Worth looking at my answer (below) because it changes the encoding.

Answer (score -3):

**IMPORTANT:**

If you don't set the encoding, many softwares can break.  git is a very popular example.

`Set-Content "your_ignore_file.txt" .gitignore -Encoding utf8` **this is case-sensitive** and forces utf8 encoding!

Comment: How is the encoding relevant for creating an **empty** file? A null byte file doesn't need any encoding and it's tricky to mark it with a BOM (0 bytes)

Comment: @jeb because people fill empty files, and when filled files are used as settings files, they create errors when they are not UTF8.  In fact, I would say people almost always fill files and don't leave them blank, and I wouldn't use any other method to create a blank file that I later intended to alter because I nearly always want to be certain that my files are UTF8. For example, the .git tutorial on github asks the user to make a blank file which is filled later, and the other method makes a file with weird Windows encoding.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08, the file encoding is not stored in a special attribute or in some other magical secret area, it is just reflected by the data it contains; if there is no data, there cannot be an encoding…

Comment: @aschipfl A blank file must contain some data, then.  If you create a blank file and explicitly flag utf8, the file works after it is later populated; on the other hand, if you create a blank file and ostensibly allow default encoding (ASCII), when you later fill the file it will break whatever program requires UT8 encoding.  I have first-hand experience of this, and anybody can test it.  Regardless of your incredulity, this is demonstrably true and tolerates empirical testing: I think the negative feedback is totally unwarranted and damages the accessibility of this important info. Prove it.

Comment: A blank file is a blank file, there is no data inside; otherwise, it would not be blank (empty, 0 bytes), would it? You seem to work with a versioning tool (git), which stores some meta-data for each file, apparently including its encoding. But the blank file itself definitely does not hold any encoding setting, neither in the data area (0 bytes obviously hold no information), nor in the file table of the file system (FAT, NTFS, or whatever you may use)…