# How can I create an empty file at the command line in Windows?

Tags: windows, file, cmd, command-line

How can I create an empty file at the DOS/Windows command-line?

I tried:

```
copy nul > file.txt
```

But it always displays that a file was copied.

Is there another method in the standard cmd?

It should be a method that does not require the [touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_%28Unix%29) command from Cygwin or any other nonstandard commands.
The command needs to run from a script, so keystrokes cannot be used.

Comment: Just found a true batch command resulting in an empty file (0 byte): I have updated my answer.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201, "How to create empty text file from a batch file?". (But, IMHO, the answers are better here.)

Comment: Yes, the command copy nul > file.txt is created having the text "1 file(s) copied." Empty file is not created.

Comment: This to me just proves that MS-DOS is garbage if you cannot create a plain empty file with one command.

Comment: @KolobCanyon: you can, of course, per the answers already posted.  But do you really think the ability to quickly create an empty file should be a priority for an operating system aimed at end users and needing to run in 16K of RAM?  It's not a particularly useful thing to do, after all, except in a few rare edge cases.

Comment: Don't redirect the output from copy (which is *1 file(s) copied*). Copy nul to the file: 
  **copy nul emptyFile.txt**

Comment: `cd > "filename.extension"`  should do the job e.g `cd > file.txt`

Comment: MSDos will delete any 0 byte files that you try to copy. Windows doesn't.

Answer (score 715, accepted):

*Without* redirection, [Luc Vu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5423827/luc-vu) or [Erik Konstantopoulos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2474955/erik-konstantopoulos) [point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34460123/6309) [out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32296375/6309) to:

```
copy NUL EMptyFile.txt
copy /b NUL EmptyFile.txt
```

---

"[How to create empty text file from a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210201/6309)" (2008) also points to:

```
type NUL > EmptyFile.txt
# also
echo. 2>EmptyFile.txt
copy nul file.txt > nul # also in qid's answer below
REM. > empty.file
fsutil file createnew file.cmd 0 # to create a file on a mapped drive
```

---

[Nomad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3040932/nomad) mentions [an original one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20237561/6309):

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\tests>aaaa > empty_file
'aaaa' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\VonC\prog\tests>dir

 Folder C:\Users\VonC\prog\tests

27/11/2013  10:40    <REP>          .
27/11/2013  10:40    <REP>          ..
27/11/2013  10:40                 0 empty_file
```

In the same spirit, [Samuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/840405/samuel) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702762/how-to-create-an-empty-file-at-the-command-line-in-windows/43677896#comment74402568_1702790):

> the shortest one I use is basically the one by Nomad:

```
.>out.txt
```

It does give an error:

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

But this error is on stderr. And `>` only redirects stdout, where *nothing* have been produced.
Hence the creation of an *empty* file.
The error message can be disregarded here. Or, as in [Rain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5999372/rain)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64419773/6309), redirected to `NUL`:

```
.>out.txt 2>NUL
```

---

(Original answer, November 2009)

```
echo.>filename
```

(`echo ""` would actually put "" in the file! And `echo` without the '.' would put "`Command ECHO activated`" in the file...)

Note: the resulting file is not *empty* but includes a return line sequence: 2 bytes.

---

This [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win2000.cmdprompt.admin/msg/092e5cc12148ce2f?pli=1) points to a true batch solution for a real *empty* file:

```
 <nul (set/p z=) >filename

 dir filename
 11/09/2009  19:45                 0 filename
 1 file(s)                         0 bytes
```

> The "`<nul`" pipes a `nul` response to the `set/p` command, which will cause the
> variable used to remain unchanged. As usual with `set/p`, the string to the
> right of the equal sign is displayed as a prompt with no CRLF.

Since here the "string to the right of the equal sign" is empty... the result is an empty file.

---

The difference with `cd. > filename` (which is mentioned in [Patrick Cuff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702762/how-to-create-an-empty-file-in-the-command-line/1703040#1703040) and does also produce a 0-byte-length file) is that this "bit of redirection" (the `<nul...` trick) can be used to **echo lines without any CR**:

```
<nul (set/p z=hello) >out.txt
<nul (set/p z= world!) >>out.txt
dir out.txt
```

> The `dir` command should indicate the file size as 11 bytes: "`helloworld!`".

Comment: you'd actually want `echo.>filename` because it will include the space as well as the newline character.

Comment: Using the `rem` command avoids creating a file with an empty line in it.

Comment: @Agent_9191: true, I have updated my answer. @Greg: not sure what you mean: `rem>filename` produces the same result (2 bytes)

Comment: I recall the `rem` trick worked in the past (maybe only DOS?), but apparently not today!

Comment: Noufal Ibrahim: don't let this fool you; just see the next answer which has a much easier and equally working solution. What's done here is partially wrong in the first case (not empty but contains a line break) and way overcomplicated in the second one.

Comment: @VonC Doing Samuel's suggest,  `.>out.txt` just gives an error " `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`  "

Comment: @barlop Yes: that is the point: it triggers some error message on stderr, but *nothing* (empty string) on stdout. And `>` redirect stdout only to `out.txt`. Hence the creation of an empty file. You can disregard the error message in this context.

Comment: Note that `copy` is a batch builtin so it won't work with e.g. Python's `subprocess.run`

Comment: @xjcl True. I suppose you would need to call that shell in order to execute its builtin command, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485749/6309.

Comment: In my particular case I've just emulated it using https://stackoverflow.com/q/1158076/2111778

Answer (score 307):

Try this:

```
type NUL > 1.txt
```

this will definitely create an empty file.

Comment: This adds "NUL is ./NUL" to the file

Answer (score 194):

Here's another way:

```
cd . > filename
```

Comment: "cd. > filename" creates empty file else you will have filepath printed in your newly created file using "cd > filename" command.

Comment: Use this: `cd . > filename.extension` Meaning you need a space between `cd` and `.`

Comment: Finally an option that didn't give me an ugly error!  I cannot believe that there is not a simple command to create a file in the Windows.  How did they miss that?

Comment: This is the easiest answer. Why isn't it checked?

Comment: Can anybody explain how this trick actually works under the hood? Why changing to the current folder does not produce any output?

Answer (score 83):

If you really want a totally empty file, without any output to stdout, you can cheat a little:

```
copy nul file.txt > nul
```

Just redirect stdout to nul, and the output from copy disappears.

Comment: It fails if the file.txt exists.

Comment: Failing if the file exists is good behavior as I understand the question.

Answer (score 69):

**Open file:**

```
type file.txt
```

**New file:**

- Way 1: `type nul > file.txt`
- Way 2: `echo "This is a sample text file" > sample.txt`
- Way 3: `notepad myfile.txt` <press <kbd>Enter</kbd>>

**Edit content:**

```
notepad file.txt
```

**Copy**

```
copy file1.txt file1_copy.txt
```

**Rename**

- Way 1: `rename file1.txt file1_rename.txt`
- Way 2: `ren file1.txt file1_rename.txt`
- Way 3: `move file1.txt ./file1_rename.txt`

**Move file:**

```
move file1.txt path/where/to/move/
```

Also you can rename file while moving:

```
move file1.txt path/where/to/move/file1_rename.txt
```

**Delete file:**

```
del file.txt
```

Comment: more > filename.txt   than   CTRL + C.

Answer (score 51):

```
call>file.txt
```

This is the cleanest way I know.

Comment: What is it about this that is "clean"?

Comment: it outputs nothing to the file while being easy to remember and use.

Comment: How does it work? It is calling a script with an empty name(?) What is the result and possible side effects (e.g., to standard error)? Isn't there a less obscure way? Couldn't `ZZ` be used instead of `call` (not that it is less obscure)? - like [Nomad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702762/how-can-i-create-an-empty-file-at-the-command-line-in-windows/20237561#20237561).

Comment: @PeterMortensen It makes a call to a nonexistent subroutine (because there can't be an un-named subroutine).  It doesn't cause an error, which you can test by running `call && echo test` or `call || echo test`. The and/or is based on the errorlevel of the previous command. Furthermore, the answer you referenced suggesting it is a better solution, is very dangerous. as others have already noted in the comments on that answer, depending on a command not existing is terrible, because if it does exist you just ran it with no clue what it does, potentially with more permissions than it should have.

Comment: @PeterMortensen bottom line, nomad's answer is dangerous, call has zero side effects and doesn't raise an error, and if you want a less obscure way, maybe use powershell or python or literally anything else? and maybe don't dig through obscure answers from nearly a decade ago about something that was archaic even back then.

Answer (score 46):

```
echo "" > filename
```

I believe this works on Windows/DOS, but my last hands-on experience with either is quite a while ago. I do know for a fact that it works on basically any [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) compliant OS.

Comment: Apperantly, VonC's answer is better than mine, so please upvote that instead.

Comment: Unfortunately: echo "" displays double quotes and they are written to the file when stream is redirected to it.

The same happens with just: echo > filename  because it writes ECHO is off/on to the file as well.

Comment: maybe you could put "@echo off" on the line before creating the file to circumvent that?

Comment: short and simple. thanks

Comment: In Windows/DOS `echo "" > file.txt` writes two double quotes into the file and also some not printable characters (20 and 0D) and then the newline character (0A).
In UNIX systems this command creates not empty file with the newline character (0A).
So `echo "" > file.txt` doesn't create an empty file.
Use `type nul > file.txt` in Windows and `touch file.txt` in UNIX.

Answer (score 37):

On the Windows command-line, one way would be to use [fsutil](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil.mspx):

```
fsutil file createnew <filename> <size>
```

An example:

```
fsutil file createnew myEmptyFile.txt 0
```

---

Below is for *nix command-line.

```
touch filename
```

This command changes your modified date of a file or creates it if file is not found.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question specifically states, "Without the touch command from Cygwin."

Comment: There exist non-Cygwin implementations of the touch command: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ is good.

Comment: In *nix, I'm personally partial to a simple `> filename`, which can also be used to truncate an existing file.

Comment: `fsutil` needs administrative privileges. That's a bit much to ask for simply creating an empty file ...

Comment: @Joey Aren't all these commands a bit much to create an empty file?  Even the one below with 120 points is a lot when you are used to touch.

Answer (score 15):

You can write your own touch.

```
//touch.cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv;)
{
  if(argc !=2)
  {
    std::cerr << "Must supply a filename as argument" << endl;
    return 1;
  }
  std::ofstream foo(argv[1]);
  foo.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

For creating any type of file you can use the following code

```
type nul > (file_name).(file_type)
```

For example, if you want to create a text file then

```
type nul > demo.txt
```

If you want to create a JavaScript file then

```
type nul > demo.js
```

Answer (score 14):

```
cd > filename.cfg
```

worked when creating a file in C:/Program Files where you don't have the access to create files directly.

Comment: What is supposed to happen? How is it circumventing basic security? Can you elaborate? Preferably, by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49040428/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 9):

`copy con SomeFile.txt` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I precised the question that the command will run from script so unfortunately any keyboard interaction does not work.

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 9):

You can create an empty file with

```
'' > newfile.txt
```

Navigate to the directory and type the above command in a PowerShell window.

*Note that this will not work on the Windows command prompt.*

Answer (score 7):

Yet another method that creates a zero byte file:

```
break > "file.txt"
```

Comment: How does it work? What is the theory of operation? [`break` is an unknown command](https://ss64.com/nt/), only resulting in outputting to standard error? Or something else?

Answer (score 7):

`type nul > filename` will create a new empty file.

Also `copy nul filename` works without redirecting (more obvious solution).

Comment: At least it is not an obscure solution, like many of the other answers.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use:

```
echo. 2>foo
```

The debug output for `echo.` will almost definitely be empty.

Answer (score 6):

Use `copy > your_file_name.extension` in command prompt
like

```
P:\excecise> copy > Sample.txt
```

Comment: What is "excecise"? Do you mean [exercise](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exercise#Noun)? Or something else?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the old command

```
copy con file_name.ext
```

Don't type anything. Just press <kbd>F6</kbd> to save it. However, it will print "File copied", but when you open the file, it will be empty.

Comment: How does this work? Why does it work? Is `con` some reserved thingamabob? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50424163/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: As I wrote, dun type anything, just press F6

Comment: This was one of the original ways to do this, because like Peter asked, yes, Con is a reserved word.  If you want to test it, try changing a directory name to CON and see how it is not pleased with your life choice.

Answer (score 6):

```
. >> file.txt
```

- `>>` appends [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) into a file
- `.` is just a wrong command to pass the empty standard output to `>>`

However, you'll see [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr))'s output in the `CMD`:

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

You can suppress this error message (if you want) by redirecting standard error to `NUL`.

```
. >> file.txt 2> nul
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me,

```
echo > file.extension
```

Here's another way I found today. I got ideas from other answers, but it worked:

```
sometext > filename.extension
```

For example,

```
xyz > emptyfile.txt  //this would create an empty zero byte text file
abc > filename.mp4   //this would create an zero byte MP4 video media file
```

This would show an error message in the command prompt that,

*`xyz` is not as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

But the weird thing I found was the file is being created in the directory even if the command is not a standard Windows command.

Comment: There are more than one "handles" that console applications can read/write to. The standard ones are: (0) STDIN, (1) STDOUT, and (2) STDERR. 

I believe the reason your trick works here is because all of the output is going to the error handle but you're only directing STDOUT to the file. Try doing: "xyz > emptyfile.txt 2>&1" to redirect STDERR to whatever STDOUT is using, which happens to be redirecting to 
"emptyfile.txt".You should see the error message inside that file now.

Comment: The first one will *not* result in an empty file. It will contain 13 characters (11 ordinary characters + CR + LF): *"ECHO is on."*

Answer (score 5):

I read many threads but it is not the shortest way.

Please use command:

`>copy /b NUL  empty_file.txt`

Comment: Why does it work? What is the theory of operation? For example, why is the leading `>` necessary (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: > at begin of line is common to show you type text after in command line only. This copy NUL file (which contain 0 bytes). so it should work.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
echo $null >> filename
```

See: *[Equivalent of Linux `touch` to create an empty file with PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/502374/equivalent-of-linux-touch-to-create-an-empty-file-with-powershell)*

Answer (score 5):

**On Windows**

I tried doing this

```
echo off > fff1.txt
```

And it created a file named *fff1.txt* with a file size of 0 KB.

I didn't find any commands other than this that could create a empty file.

> Note: You have to be in the directory you wish to create the file.

Comment: don't forget to echo on after creating file if you need.

Comment: I am not sure about why it does so, but I guess that you should do "echo on" after entering the above command.

Comment: Re *"I didn't find any commands other than this that could create a empty file."*: So you didn't look at any of the previous 30+ answers here?

Answer (score 5):

- Create a bat file with content `echo '' > %1` (name the file as touch.bat).
- Add the folder to the PATH environment variable.
- You can use touch to create files. (for example: `touch temp.txt` creates the *temp.txt* file)

Check [this article](https://dev.to/pranay_rauthu/bashrc-alternative-in-windows-kib) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

There are also other easy ways to create files.

For example, you can create file and open it with **notepad** from **cmd**

```
notepad newFile.txt
```

This will prompt you that there is no such file and if you want to create it as a new file.

You can create any kind of file like this.

For example,

```
notepad newFile.js
```

OR

```
notepad newFile.py
```

Not only **Notepad**, you can also use other apps to do so. E.g, you can use **Visual Studio Code** to create and open new files.

For example,

```
code newFile.py
```

This will create a new Python file and open it in vs code (if you have vs code installed).

You can also create other types of files with this method also.

Comment: Already mentioned several times and discarded each time because it needs user intervention.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :`abc > myFile.txt`
First, it will create a file with name `myFile.txt` in present working directory (in command prompt). Then it will run the command `abc` which is not a valid command. In this way, you have gotten a new empty file with the name `myFile.txt`.

Comment: This could be very wrong if `abc` was in the path and was a convenience function for formatting all the drives except the installation directory.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way:

```
copy nul 2> empty_file.txt
```

Comment: Why does it work? What is the theory of operation?

Answer (score 3):

I have just tried in Windows:

```
copy con file.txt
```

Then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

And it worked for me.

**For Ubuntu, usually I am creating a file using the `vi` command**

```
vi file.txt
```

It will open the file. Then press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. Then type **:wp** and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. It will create a new file with empty data.

Comment: The question said *"The command needs to run from a script, so keystrokes cannot be used."*.

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another way:

```
rem/ > file.ext
```

The slash `/` is mandatory; without it the redirection part is commented out by `rem`.

Comment: This actually works in DOSBox, unlike many of the other solutions here. Trying to `echo` nothing into a file adds a line break, using `NUL` seems to fill up a file endlessly, and if you try executing a nonexistent command, DOSBox will redirects the actual OS response on that to the text file.

Answer (score 1):

First create your file so that it exists:

```
echo . > myfile.txt
```

Then overwrite the created file with an empty version using the `copy` command:

```
copy /y nul myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo. | set /p=>file
```

`echo.` suppresses the "Command ECHO activated"

`| set /p=` prevents newline (and the file is now 0 byte)

Answer (score 1):

This will change the command line window title, but it will also create a empty file.

```
title > file.txt
```

Comment: The suspense! What will it change the command line window title to?

Comment: Empty / no title?

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty file, Windows PowerShell:

> ```
> echo fileName.fileExtension
> ```

If you want to open in Notepad:

> ```
> nodepad fileName.fileExtension
> ```

Answer (score -1):

`echo` is the command that creates a file with the text you pass it to as argument.

for example, if you want to create a file named `navin.txt` with `Navin is a web developer` in it`.

then do `echo "Navin is a web developer` in it" > navin.txt

in case you want your new file to be totally empty, just leave the strings empty like this- `echo "" > filename.txt"`

a new file will be created with the given text.

Comment: The question is about creating an empty file, not a file with content. With `echo` it's not possible to create an empty file

Comment: it's possible to create an empty file with echo. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: It's still not empty `echo ""` creates a file containing two double quotes and `\r\n`. Even on linux, with sh or bash it creates a file with one byte `\n`

Comment: You can create a zero byte file using echo with additional commands -- `echo: | tr -d '\r\n' | findstr /v "^$" > C:\zerobyte_file.txt`.  Adding only `tr -d '\r\n'` or `findstr /v "^$"` creates a one byte or three byte file.

Answer (score -2):

Run CMD in administrator mode and type this:

```
NUL > file_name.extention
```

Or you type this

```
echo .> file_name.extention
```

Or

```
echo .
```

Comment: Why is administrator mode necessary (not a rhetorical question)? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43677896/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: `echo . ` creates a file with 3 bytes,a dot and CRLF, that is not an empty file. `NUL` is not a command, it shows an error message or in case of a new Win10 a popup message appears