# Python: get output of the shell command 'history'

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

My end goal is capture the previous command executed in the terminal. Since ~/.bash_history doesn't include commands from the current terminal session, I can't simply read that file.

From another thread, I found this script:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
shell_command = 'bash -i -c "history -r; history"'
event = Popen(shell_command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, 
    stderr=STDOUT)

output = event.communicate()
```

That's pretty close to what I'm looking for, but it also will not include the history from the current terminal session since it's started as a subprocess.  Is there any way to execute a similar command in the current shell?

Comment: `history` isn't an executable, it's a shell builtin.

Comment: Check [a question on how to run bash built-ins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460923/run-bash-built-in-commands-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why don't you read the file directly.
**~/.bash_history**

```
for history in open('/home/user/.bash_history'):
    print(history, end='')
```

Comment: Because my end goal is capture the previous command executed in the terminal, and ~/.bash_history doesn't include commands from the current terminal session.

Comment: I should make that more clear in the original question.  Thanks for the advice, though.

Comment: That's the default behaviour but you could write a function to make the shell append the previous command to the history file before prompting for a new command.