# read timestamped shell history from python2

Tags: python, shell

I would like to know if it is possible to read the output of `history` shell command from python2.

I tried:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("history",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT )
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    print line
retval = p.wait()
```

just for testing but I got nothing - no output - no print. This code worked with `ls`

Also I want to add the timestamp

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

**UPDATE**
I just realized that `history` is not in `/usr/bin/ls`

```
[Jobs:2]  dnl@user ->  whereis history
history: /usr/share/man/man3/history.3.gz /usr/share/man/mann/history.n.gz /usr/share/info/history.info.gz
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: get output of the shell command 'history'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319605/python-get-output-of-the-shell-command-history)

Comment: I tried that solutions. The `~/.bash_history`  also shows the output. on the other hand `history` only prints the executed commands and it can be timestamped