# Get all command line arguments in python

Tags: python

When I run `python3 myscript.py foo bar 123` then `sys.argv` holds the value `['myscript.py', 'foo', 'bar', '123']`. I'd like to access the name of the command itself (`python3` in this case). How can I do that?

Comment: Isn' t it always python3 if you are running python 3? What could this be useful for?

Comment: @liakoyras It could be `python3.7` or `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: I don't believe that's possible from the python script, though I could certainly be wrong. Do you just need to know which version of python you are running: `sys.version_info`?

Comment: Which operating system?? Which command shell?

Comment: related: [Python: get output of the shell command 'history'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319605/python-get-output-of-the-shell-command-history)

Comment: @IanRehwinkel: Use the module `psutil` and get the `commandline`, find the `pythonX` process running your `.py`.

Comment: @stovfl That works! Thank you so much! Post it as an answer so I can mark this question as solved.

Comment: @IanRehwinkel: Feel free to post a community wiki answer, checkbox lower right, to show your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `psutil` module (can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/)), it is possible to retrieve all command line arguments used:

```py
psutil.Process().cmdline()
```

It returns a list of strings, including the command used to start the python interpreter (e.g. `/usr/bin/python3`).