# How to get the current shell command line when I run a python script?

Tags: python

If I have a scripts test.py which contains some arguments.
I run this shell

```
python test.py --a this_a --b this_b
```

I want to get this string `python test.py --a this_a --b this_b` in test.py. How can I get this?

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117530/sys-argv1-meaning-in-script

Comment: If you wanted the full path to the python executable too, you could use `sys.orig_argv` instead of just `sys.argv`

Comment: I’m not so sure this is a duplicate. At any rate, there’s really no portable way of retrieving the original command line, since that is never passed into the process. There might not even *be* a command line, depending on how the process is launched. What exact purpose do you need the command line string for?

Comment: The duplicate ref is wrong, since `sys.argv` starts with the script name, and doesn't contain the entire command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Get all command line arguments in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57935592/770830)?

Comment: @bereal I trust you are aware that you can change the list of duplicates without reopening?

Comment: @tripleee I am, but I was not sure that it was what the OP wanted, so I asked.