# Detect Python Entrypoint Value

Tags: python

I understand the below stuff

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='rocket',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'rocket = rocket:main',
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is the way I could start the script

```
python test.py
```

or

```
rocket test.py
```

I need to be able to detect inside the test.py how the script started.

**Question Redefined**
I use https://github.com/microsoft/DeepSpeed framework

So when I use

```
deepspeed run.py ....
```

I got

```
['/..../anaconda/envs/deepspeed/bin/python', '-u', '/.../run.py', ...]
```

When I ran

```
python run.py ....
```

I got

```
['python', '/.../run.py', ....]
```

But some users may run

```
/.../anaconda/envs/deepspeed/bin/python run.py ...
```

and then I have again the same problem

```
['/..../anaconda/envs/deepspeed/bin/python', '/.../run.py'
```

I know the difference is -u but it is a bit lame approach I would imagine? Any thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935592/get-all-command-line-arguments-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all command line arguments in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935592/get-all-command-line-arguments-in-python)