# subprocess.run() doesn't return any output

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I can't figure out why my code doesn't return any output. I'm running python 3.8

```
bash_command = ['compgen', '-c']
process = subprocess.run(bash_command,
                         check=True,
                         text=True,
                         shell=True,
                         executable='/bin/bash',
                         capture_output=True
                         )

software_list = process.stdout.split('\n')
print(software_list)
```

Print gives me empty list: ['']

EDIT:

1. compgen is bash command which lists all available commands, both built-ins and installed programs available in PATH
2. I have compgen installed on my machine

Comment: Please add `print(process)` immediately before `software_list = process.stdout.split('\n')` and write what it is output.

Comment: What does `print(repr(process))` show?

Comment: both print(process) and print(repr(process)) returned:

CompletedProcess(args=['compgen', '-c'], returncode=0, stdout='', stderr='')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subprocess library won't execute compgen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550650/subprocess-library-wont-execute-compgen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a program specifying `shell=True`, the command argument can be a single string instead of a list of strings. This is one instance where it needs to be a single string:

```py
import subprocess


bash_command = 'compgen -c' # single string
process = subprocess.run(bash_command,
                         check=True,
                         text=True,
                         shell=True,
                         executable='/bin/bash',
                         capture_output=True
                         )

software_list = process.stdout.split('\n')
print(software_list)
```