# Linux History to Python Variable

Tags: python, linux, bash, history, io-redirection

I have found some close answers, but nothing on the topic. In short, how do I redirect the output of Linux History command to a Python variable?  The normal history file does not have all the activity, and I do not have permission to access the file directly.  Here is what I have so far, it appears that the variable does not populate:

```
import subprocess
a= subprocess.check_output("history | cut -c 8-", shell=True)

for line in a:
        print line
```

Comment: What output your code is giving?

Comment: It gives no output at all.  No error message either.  I think this is a redirect problem but I am not sure.

Comment: Whooops. [Meant this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460923/run-bash-built-in-commands-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

It seems at least a part of the problem is that using `shell=True` with `subprocess` in linux starts a new `/bin/sh` process with the command as an argument.

Also, the history command works when in interactive mode (when the shell is started with a `-i` flag).

The following command should work:

```
import subprocess
a= subprocess.check_output('echo "history" | /bin/bash -i', shell=True)

for line in a:
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out.

```
import subprocess
try:
    cmd = 'bash -i -c "history -r;history | cut -c 8-"'
    a= subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True,stderr= subprocess.STDOUT)

    for line in a.splitlines():
        print line
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print "Error while executing command"
```

**Output:**

```
[root@dsp-centos ~]# python a.py 
vi get_stat.py
python test.py
vi get_stat.py
python test.py
vi get_stat.py
[root@dsp-centos ~]#
```