# Create a new file in git bash

Tags: git, bash, shell, github

I've got Git for Windows running, I'm not sure if it's supposed to function as a text editor though?

I think I installed it with the Vim editor, but in a Git Bash shell how do I create a file, such as webpage.html?

```
$ git add webpage.html
```

comes back as

```
fatal: pathspec 'webpage.html' did not match any files
```

because it tries to track a non-existing file.

I understand I can create a new file on the github.com interface, that's easy enough, I'm wondering if I can create a new file (like echo in cmd) and whether this file will actually be blank ([echo in cmd creates non-blank files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702762/how-to-create-an-empty-file-at-the-command-line)) and how I can write into that file from the git bash shell?

If not, I'm guessing I should just create a new file in windows explorer? Is that the norm...?

#### **Edit**

Wow, I was new to all this when I asked the above. No, Git Bash isn't a text editor, it's a Windows version of the `git` facility on Unix, and only handles the file versioning. `git add`, `git rm`, and other `git` commands just handle how the version control file manager handles the files and folders, and the only things it changes as a result are in a hidden folder named `.git`. Sorry if this has confused anyone.

I was confused at the time because, as the name suggests, Git Bash has bash shell commands shipped with it, not just `git` - e.g. `ls` (list files), `mkdir` (make new folder), and -- what I was looking for -- `touch` (make a new file or update timestamp on existing file), and `echo` (print text to the command line, or direct that text to a file).

I could have made my new file `webpage.html` with:

```
touch webpage.html
```

Then written to it with:

```
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>" > webpage.html
```

Then appended lines to it with:

```
echo "<html" >> webpage.html
echo "<head>" >> webpage.html
```

and so on - but I don't think there's any text editor (according to [this list of commands](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457305/Basic-Git-Command-Line-Reference-for-Windows-Users)). See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows) for details of setting up a text editor with Git on Windows.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you are using the Git **Bash** shell, you can use the following trick:

```
> webpage.html
```

This is actually the same as:

```
echo "" > webpage.html
```

Then, you can use `git add webpage.html` to stage the file.

Comment: Does $.gitignore do not work??                                  $echo "" > .gitignore worked however.                              I am on Win 7 machine with git version 1.9.4

Comment: @Dexter - Did you try `> .gitignore`? Note the `>`.

Comment: Excellent solution. This is really easy, do you maybe know why there is no command like `git create index.html`?

Comment: There's a command already for this: `touch webpage.html`. It will create an empty file. It is available in Git bash as well as MSYS2.

Answer (score 15):

This is a very simple to create file in git bash at first write **touch** then file name with extension

**for example**

```
touch filename.extension
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a file using Git

```
touch fileName
```

Create a folder using Git

```
mkdir folderName
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Just create files in the windows explorer and git automatically detects these files as currently untracked. Then add it with the command you already mentioned.

`git add` does not create any files. See also http://gitref.org/basic/#add

Github probably creates the file with `touch` and adds the file for tracking automatically. You can do this on the `bash` as well.

Comment: So you mean I can create a file with
"$ git touch webpage.html"
?

Comment: Well, yes and no. `git touch` is no official command, however you can create an alias for the two bash commands `touch $1 && git add $1`. `touch` is a bash command. See https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases. You could also have a look on these git extras: https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras which contain `git touch` already

Answer (score 0):

echo "" > emptyfile.txt