# Is it possible to display a list of all changed files in all commits of a branch in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, I have a project using Git and would like to generate a list of all changed files within a branch as compared to the master branch. If a file were modified in many commits, it should be listed only once.

I have no preference on how the list is output, so long as I can read it.

If this cannot be accomplished in Visual Studio 2017 directly or with a compatible extension, I would be interested in using a third-party tool if one exists.

Comment: If you want only the filenames tyou can simply do `git diff --name-only branch master`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
git diff --name-only BRANCH master
```

It will output a list of files that are different between the two branches, relative to the root of the repository.

Comment: Additionally, this can be output to a file. I'm using Git Bash on Windows 10, so I ran the following command:


`git diff --name-only develop master > updates.html`


Source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18997095/1272050)