# Is there a Windows equivalent to `touch` to create a new file in cmd?

Tags: cmd

In Mac OS a new file can be created from the terminal by using the `touch` command. For example: 
`$ touch hello_world.rb`.
 Is there a way to create a new file of any type in cmd for Windows?

Comment: Have you tried to research?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702762/how-to-create-an-empty-file-at-the-command-line-in-windows

Comment: Yeah I though that was only for .txt but I was mistaken.

Comment: Well, an empty file is an empty file, there is no empty binary or text file since there is no data at all...

Answer (score 11):

To make a file with some text, do

```
echo some_text > hello_world.rb
```

Or, as seen in the comments,

```
type nul > hello_world.rb
```

(Note that you actually type `type`.)

Comment: This does definitely not create an empty file!

Comment: type nul  > fileName.txt, This creates empty file and works on windows 10.

Comment: Idea how to do a multiple file command? (also different types) easily?

Comment: echo nul > hello_world.rb

Comment: @itay_alon That actually puts the text 'nul' in the file, on Windows 7.