# How can I create a ClearCase branch type without a comment?

Tags: branch, clearcase

Can I create a ClearCase branch type without a comment?

I realize I can use an empty comment, but will ClearCase consider that to be the same as  no comment? e.g. not display it as an empty line etc.?

Answer (score 0):

> e.g. not display it as an empty line

It would still display the branch type (in a [cleartool lstype -kind brtype](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lstype.htm) command)

Only a `locked -obsolete` brtype would not be listed (comment or not)

Comment: So, an empty comment is the best I can do then? Also, perhaps I could point you at [this related question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/404911/what-to-put-in-which-kind-of-comment-in-clearcase) on Programmers.SX .

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, unless you really want the branch type to be invisible, in which case only lock -obs gives you that (but, as the term "lock" suggests, means you cannot create any new branch from it)

Comment: No, I just want a "no comment" branch which is visible, used, and unlocked.

Comment: @einpoklum So yes, even though I have not tested with `-cfile` (instead of `-c`), with an *empty* file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1702790/6309)

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing we're worried about is a comment, you can use -nc on the command line and there will be no comment associated with the brtype. If you use the GUI's, the comment field isn't a mandatory one.