# How to create multiple empty files using command prompt in Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, cmd

I am working on a project where I need to create multiple empty files. In the past, I have used the touch command, but this only allows me to create one file at a time. Is there a way to create multiple empty files using the command prompt in Windows?

I appreciate any suggestions or solutions you may have. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an empty file at the command line in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702762/how-to-create-an-empty-file-at-the-command-line-in-windows)

Comment: @dan1st - The answer indicated as duplicate only addresses how to create one (1) empty file. The OP wants to create many.

Answer (score 5):

A `FOR` loop will allow you to make as many files as you want. The following command creates ten (10) files.

```
FOR /L %A IN (1,1,10) DO (TYPE>"%TEMP%\%~A.txt" NUL)
```

If this is used in a .bat file script, be sure to double the `%` character on the variable.

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,10) DO (TYPE>"%TEMP%\%%~A.txt" NUL)
```

Comment: I get error when running this script on Windows 10 in BAT file: "%%A was unexpected at this time."

Comment: @BorisZinchenko, sorry, there needs to be a SPACE character between `IN` and `(`. Also, the first line is for use at the interacting cmd.exe prompt. The second line is for use in a .bat file script.

Comment: Thank you so much! Everybody trying to copy this line from here, be aware that you must explicitly put spaces instead of other characters copied by browser. I was totally confused. It was very hard to distinguish. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: @רועי אנגל, if you have a answer, please select what you consider to be the best answer and select the check mark for that answer. That is how SO works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `FOR` command like this:

`FOR %N IN (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z) DO (echo null > C:\temp\%N.txt)`

This will create 26 empty .txt files with one line.

If you want to clean up the files created, use this:

`FOR %N IN (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z) DO (del C:\temp\%N.txt)`

Comment: Are you sure these files are empty? Zero length?

Comment: does not work, the for %n

Answer (score 2):

Great solutions for a huge number of files although
they just didn't work for me. Here is what
worked for me using windows CMD or VScode Terminal/

**Create multiple files:**

```
ni file_name.php, other.css, thirdexample.html
```

**Create multiple directories:**

```
mkdir folder-a, folderama, library
```