# How to create empty file with no new line in it using batch script?

Tags: batch-file, echo, temp

I want to create new file and to add info in it. But at the beginning I want to clear all its information. So I wrote:

```
@if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off
@rem ############################################
@rem # Create new empty file                    #
@rem ############################################

:setup
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
goto create

:create    
@cmd /c echo( >%temp%\hosts
goto end

:end
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" endlocal
PAUSE
```

But when I open the file there is **leading** empty line

```
<empty line>
SomeInfo
```

Where  is just empty line.
How to create new file with no leading empty line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/how-to-create-empty-text-file-from-a-batch-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
break>empty.file
```

My favorite way..

Break is an internal command so it is fast.And almost allays produces empty output (he only exception is `/?`)  no matter of the arguments , which reduces the chance of errors. And never does changes to the environment.

Answer (score 3):

```
>empty.file @echo off
```

Just wanted to throw this out there, but I would recommend the `break` or `set /p` methods first.  This method along with creating a blank file will also turn command-echoing off

Also, here is an alternate method of the `set /p` method using `nul` input.

```
>empty.file set /p "=" <nul
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ECHO.|SET /P A="">empty.file
```

`SET /P` doesn't emit newlines.