# How to create a script that creates text files in every folder in a directory? (Windows Batch)

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

So basically, let's say I have the following folders in a directory:

test_folder_1

test_folder_2

And I also have a text file with the list of all the folders in that directory.

How can I create a script that will create a text file, test.txt, in all the folders in the directory? (test_folder_1 and test_folder_2)?

I tried modifying some code I found online and got this:

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%v IN (folderlist.txt) DO echo test>"C:\Users\myname\My Documents\test\"%%v""
```

However, running this, I get "Access Denied."
Any idea what went wrong, or alternative ways to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
echo test>"C:\Users\myname\My Documents\test\"%%v""
```

despite the wrong double quotes around `%%v` redirects the text `test` directly **to** the directory instead of a file `test.txt` **in** the directory. Or in other words: The attempt to create a file with name of an already existing directory is denied by Windows and the result is the access denied error message.

The solution for creating a file `test.txt` with the line `test` in each directory specified in text file `folderlist.txt` is:

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%v in (folderlist.txt) do echo test>"%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\test\%%v\test.txt"
```

It is also possible to create a file `test.txt` with a file size of 0 bytes in all subfolders of the test folder with following command line in the batch file.

```
for /D %%v in ("%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\test\*") do echo. >nul 2>"%%v\test.txt"
```

The command **FOR** returns in this case the subfolder name with full path always without surrounding double quotes even if the folder path contains a space character as it is the case here.

See [How to create empty text file from a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/) and read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for more details.

`echo. >nul 2>test.txt` results in writing just a new line to **STDOUT** redirected to device **NUL** to avoid printing lots of blank lines on batch execution to screen. And to the file `text.txt` nothing is redirected from **STDERR** as there is no error message printed by command **ECHO** resulting in creating an empty `test.txt` file.

Run in a command prompt window `for /?` for help on command **FOR**.

Comment: Thank's Mofi. Can i also ask you, why do we use %%v rather than %v? Can one % sign be used in any cases, and if so, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: You use a single % sign when you run the command directly from the command line. Double % signs are used Inside batch files.