# "Access is denied" with NUL > index.html command

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

I'm trying to setup a work environment following this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm), but am hitting an error. The tutorial says to use

```
touch index.html
```

and since I am on a windows machine, I'm trying to use

```
NUL > index.html
```

but am getting the response: `Access is denied`. I've tried running the Command Prompt as an administrator but still get the same response. How do I get around this using the command line?

---

Edit:

It gave me the Access is denied response but still created the files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create empty text file from a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/how-to-create-empty-text-file-from-a-batch-file)

Comment: I faced the same problem and git bash is a good help to go step by step with the bash commands. For that you need to install git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`touch` is a Linux command, hence you have to see the Windows equivalent to it.

you have to type `nul > filename.txt` for creating the command. Sometimes this gives the "access denied" status report which I think due to the file settings. So you can try

```
echo. > filename.txt
```

Btw you don't need to write `type` in front of it... this must be told by the author to you to type (typing -gerund form of type) it

Answer (score 1):

I got the same "**access denied**" error because I tried to use "type nul" on a folder
instead of a file. Comming from linux batch where **touch** can be used on a folder or a file, I mistakenly thought it could be done.

For touching **files** in windows command prompt:

```
type nul >> some_file_no_quotes_around_it.txt
```

For touching **folders** in windows command prompt:

```
IF NOT EXIST "./some_quoted_folder" mkdir "./some_quoted_folder"
```