# Create multiple folder, file in cmd like "mainfolder/{subfolder1, subfolder2}", "folder/{file1, file2}.js" in linux

Tags: cmd

I tried something like this in cmd

```
md mainfolder/{subfolder1, subfolder2}
touch folder/{file1, file2}.js
```

and got this error

> Missing argument in parameter list.
>
> > - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> > - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument

I think the {...} syntax is from linux.

So what is the equivalent syntax in cmd?

Comment: Try this
touch folder/{file.js, file2.js}

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
md mainfolder\subfolder1 mainfolder\subfolder2
```

`md` takes arguments separated by space. Each argument is a directory path.

Note: `md` also creates parent directory if it does not exist

```
md utils\downloads\Editor
```

is the same as:

```
MD utils 
MD utils\downloads 
MD utils\downloads\Editor
```

Source: https://ss64.com/nt/md.html

To create files see - [How to create empty text file from a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/how-to-create-empty-text-file-from-a-batch-file)

Comment: @lit my bad there.. because of my habit of working on linux/mac, I used forward slashes. I will update my answer.

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta - Thank you for updating the answer. It is a best practice to always quote paths and filenames. It will save time, frustration, money later.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd part of the question, Windows doesn't come with a touch tool.
See also this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011267/windows-equivalent-of-touch-i-e-the-node-js-way-to-create-an-index-html)

To invoke a command on a list of items use the for loop:

```
for %%A in (file1 file2) do break>"%%A.js"
```

Where `break>` will create a zero length file (or overwrite it).

For a more concise emulation of the `touch` command either use a [windows port](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) or
see [MC NDs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019017/6811411) in the mentioned question

Comment: I can agree that this will work, but it seems more obvious to use `TYPE NUL>"%%A.js"`.