# What is the meaning of cd. > for creating empty file in windows CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd

"What is the meaning of cd. > for creating empty file in windows CMD?"
In my view point CD means change directory but why i have to put .> for creating empty file in windows CMD?

```
C:\Users\smith\Desktop\web>cd. >index.html
```

Comment: Related: [How to create an empty file at the command line in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1702762) and [How to create empty text file from a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210201) Anyway, do not use `cd.` for creating an empty file! if there is a file named `cd` (no extension) in the current directory, an error arises! even if there is no such file I recommend not using this since the file system is scanned, hence this is quite slow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` redirects output from the preceding operation to a file handle. Unfortunately, there's no straighforward way to output an empty string with `echo` in cmd, so if you use:

```
echo. > newfile.txt
```

for example, you end up with `newfile.txt` containing a trailing new-line.

`cd.` "changes" the location to, well, the current location (so effectively does *nothing*) and then it outputs... well, nothing! The effect being that:

```
cd. > newfile.txt
```

results in an empty text file

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to create a zero (0) length file. This seems more explicit and probably more quickly understood.

```
COPY NUL nnn.txt
```

or

```
TYPE NUL >nnn2.txt
```

Comment: What is the meaning of COPY NUL?

Comment: @sumon, `nul` is the Null device in Windows, so you can put data into it to dismiss it or read data from it to get, well, nothing...

Comment: `NUL` on DOS/Windows is like `/dev/null` on Linux/*NIX.