# Is it possible to put a new line character in an echo line in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is it possible to put a new line character in an echo line in a batch file?

Basically I want to be able to do the equivalent of:

```
echo Hello\nWorld
```

You can do this easily enough in Linux, but I can't work out how to do it in Windows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files i think answers it.

Comment: Ahaha, yes, almost the same answer I found

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`echo.` prints an empty line.

Example:

```
echo Hello
echo.
echo world
```

prints

```
Hello

world
```

Comment: `echo.` is ~20 times slower than `echo(` and it fails completly when a file exists with the name `echo` without extension. So `echo(` is safer and faster

Comment: `echo(` doesn't work in DOS 6.22.  (Although that's probably a minimal audience at this point.)

Comment: @JimDavis +1 for DOS 6.22 compatibility

Comment: @jeb where did you get the performance information? What about `echo[`?

Comment: @Synetech I measured it with some thousand of echo's. I didn't measured `echo[` but as it fails also with a file named `echo[.bat` it should be as slow as `echo.` Infos about the echo variations at [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4554#p4554)

Answer (score 25):

It can be solved with a single echo.

You need a newline character `\n` for this.
There are multiple ways to get a new line into the `echo`

1) This sample use the multiline caret to add a newline into the command,
the empty line is required

```
echo Hello^

world
```

2) The next solution creates first a variable which contains one single line feed character.

```
set \n=^


rem ** Two empty lines are required
```

Or create the new line with a slightly modified version

```
(set \n=^
%=DONT REMOVE THIS=%
)
```

And use this character with **delayed expansion**

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Hello!\n!world
```

To use a line feed character with the **percent expansion** you need to create a more complex sequence

```
echo Hello^%\n%%\n%world
```

Or you can use the [New line hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files/269819#269819)

```
REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
set \n=^


set NL=^^^%\n%%\n%^%\n%%\n%
REM Example Usage:
echo There should be a newline%NL%inserted here.
```

But only the delayed expansion of the newline works reliable, also inside of quotes.

Comment: +1 For bringing this question back from the grave ;-)

Comment: +1, great to have the possibility to use line-feed in a variable with immediate (percent) expansion; however, Is there a way to expand a carriage-return character in the same manner without delayed expansion?

Comment: @aschipfl No, it's not possible, as all carriage returns are removed just after the percent expansion phase and there is no way to escape them

Comment: Caret (`^`) does not work in MS-DOS, at least FreeDOS. Separate `echo` commands, one per line, seem to be required.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to assign just **carriage return character** `\r` into a variable?

Comment: @Ωmega Yes, try a look at [Batch countdown timer that doesn't clear rest of output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56331593/463115) or [How to get Windows CMD ECHO to echo exactly one single character?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36068719/463115)

Comment: Thanks, I use very similar solution, but same as yours it does NOT allow to print `CR` character alone/separately, just with some non-white text in front of it. Any workaround?

Comment: @Ωmega But that is not related to this question here

Answer (score 13):

After a little experimentation I discovered that it is possible to do it without issuing two separate echo commands as described in [How can you echo a newline in batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files). However to make it work you will need a text editor that does not translate CR to CR+LF.

Type:

```
@echo First Line
```

then with NumLock on, hold down the ALT key and type 10 on the numeric keypad before releasing ALT (you *must* use the numeric keypad, not the top-row number keys).  This will insert a CR character. Then type the second line. Depending on your editor and how it handles CR compared with CR+LF you may get:

```
@echo First Line◙Second Line
```

or

```
@echo First Line
Second Line
```

This works from the command line and will work in a batch file so long as the text editor does not translate CR to CR+LF (which Windows/DOS editors do unless you configure them not to).  If the CR is converted to CR+LF, or if you use just LF, the second line is interpreted as a new command.

However, I cannot see why this would be preferable over simply:

```
@echo First Line
@echo Second Line
```

Comment: Funny, I thought I'd tried this, but I've just tried it again and it does indeed work.

Comment: I don't know which OS you tried, but your solution can't work, as a _raw_ CR is completely removed by the batch parser. In the best case a CR would move the cursor back to the line begin, not to the next line

Comment: @jeb : That would depend entirely on how the command shell handles the CR.  I tested it in Windows cmd.exe (since that is how the question is tagged), and as commented by Benj, it worked for him.  cmd.exe presumably performs the translation to CR+LF.  Most terminal emulators will support similar translation by configuration, but you are right that the technique is not generally applicable - but that was not how the question was presented.  I remain bemused regarding why anyone would want to do this, but there it is!

Comment: I assumed also windows(batch), but I just retested it and it doesn't work, I tested with a single CR(13) and also with a single LF(10) character. As I said I can't believe that your solution could work. [How does the CMD.EXE parse scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/463115) Points 1.5 and 2

Comment: Works fine on the CLI [6.3.9600] even if it doesn't work in a batch file. `I remain bemused regarding why anyone would want to do this` - I sometimes use this to make the %PATH% variable human readable: `echo %path:;=◙%`

Answer (score 6):

Ahaha,

I think I've worked out something close enough...

```
echo hello&echo.&echo world
```

Produces:

hello

world

Answer (score 1):

**echo.**
or
**echo(**

will do the blank new line. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: But this does'nt answer the question how to add a new line between two texts.

Answer (score 0):

I found this very informative, so wanted to post a better example using the answers provided

This provides a nicely formatted usage message

```
if "%1" == """" goto usage

:usage
 echo  USAGE: %0 [Set properties using -D flag] [Ant Task to Run]  &
 echo.                                                             &
 echo        Availble Command line properties                      &
 echo        --------------------------------                      &  
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not possible. You could only try an ascii-character to this:
http://www.asciitable.com/
But this will perhaps crash your batch-file.

Comment: Yeh, I had a go at this, it didn't work sadly.