# Echo line to a file on windows with a unix linebreak

Tags: windows, echo

Is there any way to have this:

```
echo test line > t.txt
```

run in a windows batch file or makefile use a unix line ending (`\n`) instead of a windows one (`\r\n`)?

Comment: Are you restricting yourself to tools that are available on a vanilla install? If not then you could use a better scripting language that .bat files.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I would really rather use only default tools. If it is totally impossible, I can accept something else, but preferably a tool to do this and not another scripting language, as I want to use this from a makefile

Comment: Which tool does not accept Windows line ends? Isn't that the tool that you should be fixing?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The "tool" is VS, and it accepts all line ends. I am just creating some source files by writing some lines into a file as it's header and then copying a whole file into it. The files I am copying are UNIX line-endings, so I end up with a file with mixed line-endings. Every time I open a file like this in VS I get prompted to convert line endings. It is annoying.

Comment: Can't you just run unix2dos on it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am not familiar with it. What is it?

Comment: Type that name into websearch.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it using `echo`. `Echo` works by simply writing a line of text followed by a CR/LF pair (the Windows line ending characters). Redirecting to a file just sends that line of text to a file handle instead of `stdout`. There's no way to modify the line ending characters used.

Answer (score 1):

Combining answers from here [Windows batch: echo without new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line) and here [Is it possible to put a new line character in an echo line in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721258/is-it-possible-to-put-a-new-line-character-in-an-echo-line-in-a-batch-file)

```
SET LF=^


REM important to have two blank lines after the SET command
<NUL set /p=test line^%LF%%LF%> t.txt
```