# How to get Windows CMD ECHO to echo exactly one single character?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

The (unofficial) documentation for the [Windows Internal CMD `ECHO`](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) shows some interesting tricks in it. However, I have not yet found a way to **echo a single character**.

Quick note, [`od`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Od_(Unix)) used below, is from a Git (or Gow) installation

For instance, this echo's the `'a'` with a 'windows' newline (`\r\n`):

```
>echo a| od -A x -t x1z -v -
000000 61 0d 0a                                         >a..<
000003
```

And this [trick](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.win2000.cmdprompt.admin/CHS0gwjZQDA/L85IIcFcLgkJ) (also in the docs now) echo's nothing:

```
><nul (set/p _any_variable=)| od -A x -t x1z -v -
000000
```

So I would expect this to echo just the 'a':

```
><nul (set/p _any_variable=a)| od -A x -t x1z -v -
000000 61 20                                            >a <
000002
```

**But it adds the extra space at the end.**

Is it possible to just do a single character?

**@Aacini answered (the first question) correctly in a comment below**, but in case he does not create an answer, here it is:

```
>set /P "=a" < NUL | od -A x -t x1z -v -
000000 61                                               >a<
000001
```

And are there any tricks to get more precise like the UNIX [`echo`](http://ss64.com/bash/echo.html) with a `-n` (no new line) and `-e` (**use backslash interpretation**) so I could similar outputs to this:

```
>unix_echo -n -e "a\n" |  od -A x -t x1z -v -
000000 61 0a                                            >a.<
000002
```

Comment: `set /P "=a" < NUL`

Comment: @Aacini, you are correct. You should answer the question. Here is the full answer to help:
>set /P "=a" < NUL | od -A x -t x1z -v -
000000 61                                               >a<
000001

Comment: IMHO the `od` command (unknown by many Windows people, including me) have _no_ relation with the method "to echo exactly one single character in Windows CMD" that is just `set /P "=a" < NUL`, so I don't see why the `od` command should appear in the answer. However, after read your edit in the question it seems to me that you are asking now about "How to emulate Unix echo command in Windows?". Perhaps I misunderstood something?

Comment: The `od` command was only there to figure out 'what' the Windows `ECHO` was doing (it just reports the stdin in hex). In particular the hidden chars. As for the secondary question, I am not so much asking how to 'emulate' the UNIX command, but rather how to be 'precise' with the Windows version, with 'precise' meaning sending non-printable ascii chars like \n and \r. But regardless, if you create an answer, I will mark it correct! Thanks for the help (maybe you could explain the solution in the answer too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `set /P` command is used to prompt the user and accept an input. For example:

```
set /P "name=Enter your name: "
```

This command show the prompt message and place the cursor after it. We may make good use of this behavior to show a "prompt" that does *not* end in CR+LF, and then complete the dummy input redirecting Stdin to NUL. In this case, the variabe name is not needed:

```
set /P "=Text with no CR+LF at end" < NUL
```

This way, to output just one character, use this:

```
set /P "=a" < NUL
```

Note that `set /P` command omit any leading space from the prompt message. This means that it is not possible to use this method to show only spaces.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks @Aacini. Is there a way to send escaped characters in the set command? "=a\n" for instance?

You also mentioned (in a comment to the question) that you didn't understand why I used `od`. I am curious how you might have debugged exactly what was being sent? Did you have an alternative method?

Comment: When I want to know _how many characters_ a command outputs, I just redirect its output to a disk file and review its size with `dir` command. When I want to know _which characters_ are stored in a file, I create an auxiliary file with the same number of a known character and then use `fc /B` command to compare the files in binary; the listing show the values of the bytes in hexadecimal. If the file to check is large, I use `fsutil file createnew file size` command to create a file of the given size initialized with binary zeros. About output control-characters, see jeb's answer below...

Comment: @JoshuaBall: About your comment: _"You also mentioned that you didn't understand why I used `od`"_, I never said _that_ (please, reread my comment). It seems that you didn't realized yet that `od` command, _or any other method_ that you or anyone may use to _check_ such output, **have no relation** with the method to echo one character in cmd.exe, that is just `set /P`. If this question is about a Windows cmd.exe feature, why the answer should include the output of an ancient Unix command completely unknow for Windows users?

Answer (score 3):

To use a newline(\n), carriage return (\r) or backspace (\b) character in an output you could create helper variables.
This variables should be used only with **delayed expansion** (or you should know what you do).

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
set \n=^
%=DO NOT MODIFY THIS LINE=%
)
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=# " %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "\b=%%a"
)
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do (
  set "\r=%%a"
)

echo Line1!\n!Line2

<nul set /p ".=Line1!\n!Line2 without"
echo  end

echo 12345!\b!*
echo 12345!\r!*
```

To echo a single space (or more) without a newline the set/p trick doesn't work, but you can create another workaround by building a temporary file with a single space.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(set LF=^
%=EMPTY=%
)
call :createSpaceFile
type spaceFile.tmp
echo After the space
exit /b

:createSpaceFile
<nul set /p ".=X!LF! " > spaceFile1.tmp
findstr /V "X" spaceFile1.tmp > spaceFile.tmp
exit /b
```

Comment: This also works: `for %%X in (^"^` & `%=EMPTY=%` & `^") do set /p "=X%%~X " > spaceFile1.tmp <nul`, and don't requires Delayed Expansion nor an additional variable.

Comment: @Aacini: I get error: `& was unexpected at this time.`. Do you have a one liner for a backspace char?

Comment: @Zimba: My code above have not any "&" character and is comprised of 3 _lines_. (Hint: code is the text over blue background).  One-liner for BS: `for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "\b=%%a"`

Comment: @Aacini: I get error when I `for %X in (^"^ & %=EMPTY=% & ^") do set /p "=X%~X " > spaceFile1.tmp <nul` on command line. Does it only work in batch file?

Comment: @Zimba: Here we comes again. As I said before, my code is comprised of **THREE LINES** (3 lines). In a Batch file the **3 lines** are: Line 1: `for %%X in (^"^` Line 2: `%=EMPTY=%` Line 3: `^") do set /p "=X%%~X " > spaceFile1.tmp <nul` This code works also from the command line, but in this case the `%=EMPTY=%` line must be replaced by an _empty line_, that is, a line that have nothing (just press the ENTER key). From the command line the **3 lines** are: Line 1: `for %X in (^"^` Line 2 is empty, so just press ENTER. Line 3: `^") do set /p "=X%~X " > spaceFile1.tmp <nul`

Comment: Please, note that my comment is placed below jeb answer, so it is related to such an answer. The code in my comment show another method to create **spaceFile1.tmp** file, that is "spaceFile" plus "1" plus ".tmp" file, so you need to also run `findstr /V "X" spaceFile1.tmp > spaceFile.tmp` line in order to get the file with spaces only. Of course, such a line also works from the command line.

Comment: Yeah I was referring to your comment below jeb's answer, which contains "&" instead of mentioning it was a new line. Thanks.

Comment: @Aacini: In Win 10 I get `13/04/2020  03:36                 3 spaceFile1.tmp
               1 File(s)              3 bytes`. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 0):

`echo` writes the given argument plus `0d0a` (CRLF).

To get one byte (character) from `echo` you'd need 2 backspace characters followed by character you want to echo.

0x08 (backspace char) can be extracted from `prompt` command.
`set` on the other hand can write one character (byte) to a file:
`(set /p = a)<nul>one.txt` echoes exactly one character 'a' to a file 'one.txt'