# Window Batch: Echo redirecting to `\n` as literal then new line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

Please read question slowly, its strange, but true.

In windows command prompt, I want `echo` redirect to print `\n` as new line to output file, but takes as literal(`\n`) instead of new line.

`echo  "A\nB\n\C\n" > temp.txt`

If I open the `temp.txt`, I see output as

> A\nB\n\C

rather then,

```
A
B
C
```

There is similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721258/is-it-possible-to-put-a-new-line-character-in-an-echo-line-in-a-batch-file?lq=1) on  Stack Overflow. However, none of answer serves my purpose.

I tried, various other options, but didn't work are:

```
echo  $'A\nB\nC' > temp.txt

echo  $'A\\nB\\nC' > temp.txt
```

etc.

So, my question, is there to achieve new line I want to achieve in redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "var=A bucket of eels\nB\nC"
(
 FOR %%a IN ("%var:\n=" "%") DO ECHO(%%~a
)>u:\x.txt
TYPE u:\x.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

`U:` is my test drive

This will show some sensitivity to some symbols.

it works by replacing each `\n` with `" "` and then enclosing the resultant string in `"`. This forms a list of quoted strings so the `for` executes the `echo` for each quoted string. The `~` removes the enclosing quotes.

Comment: Good answer but I still feel this is a duplicate question.  I would add your answer to the duplicate question I flagged above. Doesn't look like that technique was used as an answer in the question I flagged as the duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the response: [How can you echo a newline in batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files)

so for your case:

```
(echo A & echo.B & echo.C) > txt
```

Or even.. from the same topic:

```
set n=^&echo.
echo hello %n% world
```

Comment: This should be marked as a duplicate answer instead of you posting a link to the answer as an answer.