# Batch countdown timer that doesn't clear rest of output?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch timer that doesn't clear the output above it.

I have a timer function created, but am looking to improve it so that I can still view the output above it without having lines on lines of a countdown in the output. My current function is:

```
@echo off
echo KEEP THIS OUTPUT
CALL :timer 10
rem Do more things...
EXIT

:Timer
set time=%~1

:loop
cls

echo Countdown - [%time%]

set /a time=%time%-1
if %time%==0 goto timesup

ping localhost -n 2 > nul
goto loop

:timesup
echo Timer completed!!
EXIT /B 0
```

Currently, the timer clears the screen, but I would like to make it so that the output above this timer stays.

For example, at 10 seconds, the output should be:

```
KEEP THIS OUTPUT
Countdown - [10]
```

And then the output should change to:

```
KEEP THIS OUTPUT
Countdown - [9]
```

The output should NOT be:

```
KEEP THIS OUTPUT
Countdown - [10]
Countdown - [9]
```

and should NOT be:

```
Countdown - [9]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: would the [timeout](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) command be helpful? (Try `timeout 10`) If not - why?

Comment: @Stephan the timeout command does not print the output that I'm looking for, and the output is the main point of this timer. Normally it would work.

Comment: valid reason. Choose one of the answers below. Keep in mind, the `ANSI` solution doesn't work on every Windows version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with special characters, carriage return or backspace.

A carriage return moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line.
But to be on the same line as the `Countdown` text, you can't use the `echo` command, as it always appends an linefeed.
Instead I use the `set /p` command to avoid this.

```
@Echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%# in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" NUL') do set "CR=%%#"

for /L %%n in (10 -1 0) do (
    <nul set /p ".=Countdown[%%n] !CR!"
    ping localhost -n 2 > nul
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to output any length strings repeatedly to the same line is using Ansi ESC sequences
(which are supported again in the console of Windows 10 >=Treshold2).

As some editors have problems creating/saving this to a batch file, certutil is used to create it.

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\05\27\SO_56330510.cmd
@echo off
if not defined ESC call :GetEsc
echo KEEP THIS OUTPUT
CALL :timer 10
rem Do more things...
EXIT /B

:Timer
Echo Countdown - [%1]
For /l %%L in (%1,-1,0) Do Echo %Ansi%Countdown - [%%L]&Timeout /t 1 >Nul
echo %Ansi%Timer completed!!
EXIT /B 0

:GetEsc just in case you can't create and save the ESC[ sequence in your editor
echo 1B 5B>ESC.hex
Del ESC.bin >NUL 2>&1
certutil -decodehex ESC.hex ESC.bin >NUL 2>&1
Set /P ESC=<ESC.bin
set "Ansi=%ESC%1F%ESC%0J"
Del ESC.* >NUL 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

This batch file Countdown

- does not clear the rest of the screen
- is working even conditional (within a `if`)

.

```
@echo off
echo Hello

set CountDownNecessary=1

if %CountDownNecessary%==1 (
    REM ### Countdown Start ###
    set CountdownStartValue=5
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F %%# in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" NUL') do set "CR=%%#"
    for /L %%n in (!CountdownStartValue! -1 -1) do (
        <nul set /p ".=!CountdownText! !CR!"
        if not "!CountdownText!"=="" ping localhost -n 2 > nul
        set CountdownText=Proceeding in %%n seconds...
    )
    echo.
    REM ### Countdown End ###
)
echo Ready
pause
```

Output after execution of script:

> **Hello**
>
> **Proceeding in 0 seconds...**
>
> **Ready**
>
> **Press any key to continue**