# How to append an empty line in a text file using the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, scripting

How do I append an empty line in a text file using the command line?

```
 echo hi >a.txt
    echo >>a.txt
    echo arun >>a.txt
```

Here the output comes as:

```
hi
echo on
arun
```

So how could I append an empty line? I want it to be like this:

```
hi

arun
```

When I added this line on code `@echo off`, it said `echo off`. How can it be done?

Comment: I added the windows tag, since that's the only platform I can think of that would say "echo on" in response to an unqualified "echo" command. When asking questions its good to include the platform and/or language so the right people see your question. Also, Use the 010101 button to format your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How can you echo a newline in batch files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files)*.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the Windows command prompt, try:

```
echo.>> a.txt
```

Note that there is no space between `echo` and `.`; if there is one, it will output a dot. There is also no space between the `.` and the `>>`; anything in between would be output to the file, even whitespace characters.

See [the Microsoft documentation for `echo`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490897.aspx).

If this were in bash, your first try would have been correct:

```
echo >> a.txt
```

But in Windows, the unqualified `echo` command tests whether there is a command prompt or not (`echo off` turns the prompt off and `echo on` turns it back on).

Comment: Hmmm, that didn't work for me in ubuntu, recognized echo. as an unfound command.

Comment: @Tchalvak: This is a Windows question as far as we can tell from the clues in the question.

Comment: Ah, Fair enough.  What an annoying implementation of the command.

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between the dot and the redirection operator. Otherwise this will output a space followed by a line break. For some definitions of “empty line” that's not exactly empty.

Comment: Some 12 years later, I found that in a batch file, with `@echo OFF` doing this writes `ECHO IS OFF` rather than a blank line. If you add a space between the dot and the double chevron then it works as expected (i.e. `echo. >> file.txt`)

Answer (score 6):

**At Windows Prompt:**

```
echo. >> a.txt
```

**At BASH Prompt:**

```
echo >> a.txt
```

(Echo by default sends a trailing newline)

> -n     do not output the trailing newline

Answer (score -4):

It should be possible with a simple

```
echo hi\n >> a.txt
```

Comment: That will output the string literal "\n" to the file