# Do Batch files support multiline variables

Tags: windows, batch-file

If so How?

Yes, batch files are lame, but I cannot use powershell, and I don't feel like writing a real app to do this simple task....

**edit**

What i want is somthing along the lines of

```
set var="this is a 
multi 
line 
string "
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Or you can create a "real" newline character.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set NL=^


rem two empty line required
echo first line !NL! second line
set multi=Line1!NL!Line2
set multi=!multi!!NL!Line3
echo !Multi!
```

With this variant the newline is a "normal" character in the string, so the variables act normally and you can assign them to another variable, this is not possible with the `&echo.` trick (which is useful for simple tasks).

Comment: This is what I wanted originally. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Is that ok?

```
@echo off
set var=kur
set var2=kur2
echo var is = "%var%" and var2 is = %var2%
```

**edit**
is that what you mean ?

```
@echo off
set nl=^& echo.
echo this%nl%is%nl%multiline%nl%string
```

Comment: The only downside is that you can't redirect the output since it will redirect only the last line. To solve this you need to type `( ECHO this%nl%is%nl%multiline%nl%string )>NUL`

Comment: @Ameen The reason is that `this%nl%is%nl%multiline%nl%string` is not a multiline string. It happens to  expand to `this^& echo.is^& echo.multiline^& echo.string`. The outcome is the same as you'd got with only an `echo` and a multiline string but it's not just one `echo`: it's _four_ echos to get four lines. I would consider that cheating (or a party trick).

Answer (score 10):

```
SET myFlags= ^
    a ^
    b ^
    c
```

Comment: Did not work for me with `echo %myFlags%` or `echo !myFlags!`.

Comment: Try adding `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` on a separate line before the `SET`.

Comment: This is not working, even with `EnabledDelayedExpansion`

Answer (score 3):

If you just wanted to use it for outputting the lines of variables, I hope this would be useful to you.

---

Inspired by something, I found this working.

> For codes in normal Command Prompt:
>
> `set this=echo hi ^& echo bye`
>
> `%this%`

It gives out the two following two lines:

```
hi
bye
```

in the Command Prompt window.

---

The reason for using the `^` character:

Command Prompt would identify that you wanted to run two commands so that you need to add this character, that tells Command Prompt to recognize the next character as a symbol and not to do any special thing for it.

Comment: Maybe my fault but I didn't found the above answers working, therefore I posted this... 

Comment: It does works for batch-files for the "new line character" but I just wanted to add how to do the trick in normal Command Prompt environment.

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out. I had to add `^` to the `%NL%` var when putting it in the string, otherwise it hides the text after the first `%NL%` because its executing when being set, instead of when its being echoed later

```
set NL=^& echo

set str=text on line 1 ^%NL% text on line 2

echo %str%
text on line 1
text on line 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty old question, but I put together a hybrid of the solutions from  @Fabricio and @jeb that both worked correctly and added some readability:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set NL=^


rem two empty line required
set var=this is a !NL! ^
multi !NL! ^
line !NL! ^
string !NL!

echo !var!
```

Answer (score 1):

And now - without auxiliary SET commands:

```
echo this is a & echo multi & echo line & echo string
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to build something instead, not just outputting, hope this would be useful to you too.

---

*Firstly, you should make a file. Such as `.txt`. I'm going to use `var.txt` as an example.*

**Secondly, type in the multi-lines of variables.**

> Thirdly, here are the codes, but only works for batch:
>
> ```
> @echo off
> set num=0
> set /p this%num%=<"var.txt"
> goto there
>
> :there
> set /a num=num+1
> for /f "skip=%num%" %%a in (var.txt) do (set this%num% =%%a
> goto there)
> set num=0
> goto build
>
> :build
> rem Example of using multi-lines of variable.
> call echo %%this%num% %%
> set /a num=num+1
> for /f "skip=%num% delims=" %%a in (var.txt) do (call echo %%this%num% %%
> goto build)
> rem Just replace the commands with `echo` part into something else which suits your situation.
> pause >nul
> exit
> ```

I admit that strictly speaking, this is not a variable of multi-line, but in my opinion, this is better than nothing.

You may ask why not just use the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command. The reason is simply, that command does work for me *(IDK why)*. Therefore, I thought and made these codes that make the same effect.

Comment: Please feel free to ask here if there are any problems or questions with my answer.

Comment: Please refrain from stating personal opinions or experiences that do not directly refer to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice~

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this method

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM (define NewLine character)
(SET _NL=^
%=this line is empty=%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came to this kind of a specification; the `NLM` and `NL` are from https://stackoverflow.com/a/269819/6197439 - and then the trick is basically to write line by line, escaping the line ending with caret (`^`), and right before the caret, add a unique character (here `+`), which at the end will be replaced with actual newline via delayed expansion:

```bat
REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
REM use a unique character (here +) to indicate a newline, then replace it later
SET banner=Line 1 +^
Line 2 +^
Line 3

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET banner=%banner:+=!NL!%
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
echo %banner%
```

This prints in terminal:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```