# Echo newline in make script

Tags: makefile, dos

I have a make rule for compiling .c files in my project which looks like this

```
# Default rules for building r90 (avr8) / r82 (avr32) object files, from .c files.
%.$(OBJ_EXTENSION) : %.c
    @echo Compiling $(@:.$(OBJ_EXTENSION)=.c) to $@ due to change in $?
    ...
```

Now at the end of this I want a newline to nicely separate the output from the compilation of each file.

I have seen [How can you echo a newline in batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files) and similar threads and they all seem to suggest `echo.`

But on my machine `echo.` results in

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, echo., ...) failed.
```

What am I not getting?

Comment: So the first `@echo` works, but the second doesn't? I don't know ms-dos, but you could try `@echo " "`.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with 'echo', it's just that it does not like 'echo.'. 'echo " "' writes '" "'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that echo is not use the cmd.exe (windows command interpreter). Try running this from your make script instead:

```
%systemroot%\system32\cmd.exe /C "echo."
```

This runs the `echo.` command, then terminates the nested interpreter process.

Comment: I am no longer working on that project and system so I have not been able to try you suggestion. I'll set this thread to "answered" anyway to close it for now. Thank you for your input.