# How to make line breaks in the ouput .txt file made using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you echo a newline in batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files)

I'm wondering if i could have some help with making line breaks in an ouput .txt file made using a batch file.
Here's the beginning of my script, so you might see better what i mean:

```
@echo OFF
type NUL > newfile.txt
ECHO Hello, world. I am currently asking a question. > newfile.txt
```

I want the text to be output into the newfile.txt file looking like this:

```
Hello, world.
I am currently asking a question.
```

I have tried searching around alot, trying different suggestions that use `&` and `^` and `ECHO` and `ECHO.` and `$'\r'` but i haven't gotten anything to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The same question is answered in this  post.
[Inserting a carriage return in Windows batch files][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files

Comment: found this. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files][1]

Maybe it will be to your help.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files

Answer (score 3):

You can embedd linefeeds in your echo.

The empty line is required here

```
@echo off
echo Hello, world.^

I am currently asking a question. >newfile.txt
```

Or for better optics you can move the linefeed into a variable

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


rem Two empty lines are required
echo Hello, world.!LF!I am currently asking a question. >newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

One way;

```
@(
echo Hello, world
echo I am currently asking a question
echo I like cake.
) > newfile.txt
```