# how to pass input to .exe in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, command

I have a .exe which requires 3 integers as input. For example:

```
myCode.exe < input.txt
```

In input.txt:

```
2
3
8
```

Now I want to put the command in a batch file. how can I write the batch file?
(Here I want to pass 3 fixed integers in the batch file)

THANKS!

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to do this without an external file with input?

Comment: yeah. no external file. That 3 numbers are supposed to be fixed after the user first sets up the batch file

Answer (score 14):

This may also work:

```
(
echo 2
echo 3
echo 8
) | mycode.exe
```

Comment: +1, But based on way question is phrased, the OP may need the simpler `echo 1 2 3|mycode.exe`

Comment: @dbenham I wondered about that and just edited the question - they were indeed on separate lines.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

run.bat:

`myCode.exe %1 %2 %3`

call example:

`run.bat 111 222 333`

and with file:

`run.bat < input.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a batch one-liner that will create the file for you and supply it as an input to the `myCode.exe`:

```
echo 2 3 8 > output & myCode.exe output
```

Otherwise, you'll probably need to modify your program to read the arguments directly from command line.

It's possible to redirect the program standard input/output/error streams to or from a file, but I think there is no way to redirect a command line contents to a standard input stream. Take a look [at this page for details on batch redirection.](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

Comment: Now the code is in C# and is using Console.readLine() to get input. I may need to add newline between 2 and 3.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files) for embedding a newline constants in a batch file. You'll just probably need three echo statements on a line.

Comment: echo 9 && echo. && echo 19 && echo. $$ echo 2 > output | myCode.exe output                                                                  i ll try if this works. Thanks Vladimir!

Comment: It's standard practice to separate commands with an ampersand  `command1 & command2` as a pipe will confuse newbies and teach them false practices.

Comment: @foxidrive, absolutely agreed. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: The OP wants to avoid a temporary file, and the code will not work with the name of the temp file passed as an argument; it must be used as redirected input.

Answer (score 0):

try `type input.txt | myCode.exe`

Comment: `cat` is not a native `cmd` command, but a unix command (the command `type` does basically the same, but with fewer options).