# Batch file to dynamiaclly passing arguments after an .exe runs

Tags: batch-file

I have scenario where I'm running a .exe file that after running prompts for some user input. So how can I pass some parameters or user input to the .exe file using a batch file. The user input is fixed and going to be a string for `ex-ListObjects`.

NOTE:
The .exe dose not ask for any command line arguments. Once it runs its expecting user to type in
that string.

Comment: Does the executable run on command line or is does it present a GUI?

Comment: hey it has a gui i will be just running the batch file and passing the  specified string as input.so i need to write a batch file to pass the sting to the exe when it is running

Comment: If it has a GUI, then you will not be able to pass it anything from batch, as batch can not interface with a standalone GUI. If your executable's GUI is written in .NET and uses the Win32 API there *may* be some way to pass the arguments to the GUI using a Visual Basic script.

Comment: hey sorry it does not have a gui. how can i do it using bat,i will be running the bat from a .net application.

Comment: @Daemon- it would be great if u can help me with writing the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

See - [how to pass input to .exe in batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972156/how-to-pass-input-to-exe-in-batch-file)

```
(
    echo Input1
    echo Input2
) | executable.exe
```