# invoking an executable on powershell and then type commands

Tags: batch-file, powershell, executable, powershell-3.0

I am trying to call a executable file as follows

```
.\test_use.exe
```

then I press the return key to get a interface like

```
"Enter a value between 1 and 5"
```

I type 4 and get some details. Is there a way to automate it via powershell. I tried passing

```
.\test_use.exe 4
```

But it does not work. I also tried

```
$input = "4"
Invoke-command ".\test_use.exe" -InputObject $input
```

I get the following error

```
Invoke-command: Parameter cannot be resolved using the specified named characters
```

Does anyone have any pointers ??
Will it be easier to do this in batch file and store the output in a text file?

Comment: You may be interested in the WASP ( **W** indows **A** utomation **S** nap-In for **P** owershell) project over at [http://wasp.codeplex.com](http://wasp.codeplex.com). It allows for window manipulation similar to what you are referring to I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In batch you might be able to do the following:

```
(echo 4) | test_use.exe
```

See this question - [how to pass input to .exe in batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972156/how-to-pass-input-to-exe-in-batch-file)