# bat file only runs first lines command

Tags: windows

I want a .bat script to run on boot which will automatically increase the hard disk space.

```
diskpart
select volume 1
extend
exit
```

However that in a .bat file just runs the first command only. I can only get it working if I manually paste it into command prompt.

I have also tried with adding CALL before each command which did not work.

```
CALL diskpart
CALL select volume 1
CALL extend
CALL exit
```

Comment: how did you manage to assume that completely made-up commands work? I think you should do a tutorial on computers before you start scripting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line in a batch file represents a shell command or batch function. "select volume 1" is not a command that is recognized, it is text you wish to send to the running program. See [how to pass input to .exe in batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972156/) to pass input to an executable, or find out if the executable supports scripting.

DiskPart does supports scripting. Put your script in a file, say "ExtendVolume1.txt":

```
select volume 1
extend
exit
```

Then run DiskPart:

```
diskpart /s ExtendVolume1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>diskpart /?

Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: ALEX

Microsoft DiskPart syntax:
        diskpart [/s <script>] [/?]

        /s <script> - Use a DiskPart script.
        /?          - Show this help screen.
```

[A Description of the Diskpart Command-Line Utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/300415)