# Echo a blank (empty) line to the console from a Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

When outputting status messages to the console from a Windows batch file, I want to output **blank lines** to break up the output. How do I do this?

Comment: I do not believe that the question [How can you echo a newline in batch files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/132799/1497596) is a duplicate of this question. The essence of that question is: **Using a single `echo` statement, how can I output two lines of text with a newline between them?** That said, several of the answers to that question also address how to output blank (empty) lines.

Comment: Since this post is not accepting answers anymore... The correct answer is `echo:` according to the following link. http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html

Comment: In summary of the ss64 link posted for `echo`... `echo.` searches for a file named `echo` and only creates a blank line if such a file does not exist. This characteristic makes `echo.` slower and less robust than `echo:`.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

*<sup>Note: Though my original answer attracted several upvotes, I decided that I could do much better. You can find my original (simplistic and misguided) answer in the edit history.</sup>*

If Microsoft had the intent of providing a means of outputting a blank line from `cmd.exe`, Microsoft surely would have documented such a simple operation. It is this omission that motivated me to ask this question.

So, because a means for outputting a blank line from `cmd.exe` is *not* documented, arguably one should consider any suggestion for how to accomplish this to be a *hack*. That means that there is no known method for outputting a blank line from `cmd.exe` that is *guaranteed* to work (or work efficiently) in *all* situations.

With that in mind, here is a discussion of methods that have been recommended for outputting a blank line from `cmd.exe`. All recommendations are based on variations of the `echo` command.

---

```
echo.
```

While this will work in many if not most situations, ***it should be avoided*** because it is slower than its alternatives and actually can fail (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379940/1497596), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20691856/1497596), and [here](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeSnippets.php#Snippets.EchoEmptyLine)). Specifically, `cmd.exe` first searches for a file named `echo` and tries to start it. If a file named `echo` happens to exist in the current working directory, `echo.` will fail with:

```
'echo.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

---

```
echo:
echo\
```

At the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379940/1497596), the author argues that these commands can be slow, for instance if they are executed from a network drive location. A specific reason for the potential slowness is not given. But one can infer that it may have something to do with accessing the file system. (Perhaps because `:` and `\` have special meaning in a Windows file system path?)

However, some may consider these to be safe options since `:` and `\` cannot appear in a file name. For that or another reason, `echo:` is recommended by SS64.com [here](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html).

---

```
echo(
echo+
echo,
echo/
echo;
echo=
echo[
echo]
```

[This lengthy discussion](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4554) includes what I believe to be all of these. Several of these options are recommended in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379940/1497596) as well. Within the cited discussion, [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4505#p4505) ends with what appears to be a recommendation for `echo(` and `echo:`.

My question at the top of this page does not specify a version of Windows. My experimentation on Windows 10 indicates that *all* of these produce a blank line, regardless of whether files named `echo`, `echo+`, `echo,`, ..., `echo]` exist in the current working directory. (Note that my question predates the release of Windows 10. So I concede the possibility that older versions of Windows may behave differently.)

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20691856/1497596), [@jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb) asserts that `echo(` *always* works. To me, @jeb's answer implies that other options are less reliable but does not provide any detail as to why that might be. Note that @jeb contributed much valuable content to other references I have cited in this answer.

---

**Conclusion:** Do *not* use `echo.`. Of the many other options I encountered in the sources I have cited, the support for these two appears most authoritative:

```
echo(
echo:
```

But I have not found any strong evidence that the use of either of these will always be trouble-free.

---

**Example Usage:**

```
@echo off
echo Here is the first line.
echo(
echo There is a blank line above this line.
```

**Expected output:**

```
Here is the first line.

There is a blank line above this line.
```

Comment: `echo.`, `echo:`, echo\, `echo+`, `echo/`, `echo[`, and `echo]` are not safe. When used in a `for /r` loop, e.g. `for /r %a (*) do echo.%a` and so on, they append paths from the previous folder to the next one. `echo(`, `echo,`, `echo;`, and `echo=` do not have this problem.

Comment: Update: looks like Microsoft now shows to use "echo." in their Docs to "To echo a blank line on the screen". Echo Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo 
Based on the previous comments/answers it still seems like it would not be recommended to do so though. Unless this behavior has recently changed?

Comment: `ECHO.` is safe. The problem described is a problem with every command used in Windows when adding a `.` to it.  When you _**need**_ to make sure not getting the error, you can always add this to the top of your batch script: `IF EXIST echo. DEL /Q echo.`

Answer (score 210):

Any of the below three options works for you:

```
echo[

echo(

echo.
```

For example:

```
@echo off
echo There will be a blank line below
echo[
echo Above line is blank
echo( 
echo The above line is also blank.
echo. 
echo The above line is also blank.
```

Comment: Careful, "`echo.`" might not work, see the comments under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files#comment51325122_3123194

Comment: Also don't type a space between `echo .` like stupid me.

Answer (score 51):

There is often the tip to use 'echo.'

But that is slow, and it could fail with an error message, as cmd.exe will search first for a file named 'echo' (without extension) and only when the file doesn't exists it outputs an empty line.

You could use `echo(`. This is approximately 20 times faster, and it works always. The only drawback could be that it looks odd.

More about the different `ECHO:/\` variants is at [DOS tips: ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4554).

Comment: Do you have a source that highlights this issue?

Comment: IMHO it's completely pointless to worry about speed in batch - if your performance bottleneck lies in a batch file you don't try to optimize it - you throw it away to rewrite it in a real language.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, It's nothing to do with speed. If it's doing something extra (search first for a file named `echo` without extension) then it's wrong and if there's a file as such, it'll indeed fail. Extra points if the batchjob fails on a weekend while everyone is partying hard half-a-country away.

Comment: @jeb, What about newer versions of Windows?

Comment: @Pacerier It seems to be the same behaviour from XP to Win10, there are only very small changes since XP at all