# How to simulate multiple enter key press of batch file execution cmd or windows powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have batch file which I want to execute, during execution it asks for user input twice to press enter key. I want to skip this completely either by simulating the enter key press or by somehow completely overcoming it.

Edit : I can't edit the bat file to skip the program asking for user input

I have tried `echo | <yourfinecommandhere>` but this just simulates one enter key press. I am unable to simulate multiple enter key press

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cmd simply group multiple `echo`s. For example this will print 2 newlines to the pipe

```
(echo[& echo[) | command
```

[`echo(` is the most reliable way to print a new line in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20691061/995714), but in this case `echo[` is probably better. Space is significant here so there must be no space after `[`

---

In PowerShell it's easier. For example to print 3 newlines use

```
"`n`n`n" | command
```

Actually the above will print 4 new lines, because there's an implicit new line after the string. But that won't affect the output. If you want exactly 3 new lines then use

```
 Write-Output -NoNewline "`n`n`n" | command
```

Comment: The above solution worked like a charm. Thanks, phuclv.