# In a batch file, how do I echo the word "on" to a text file without turning echo on?

Tags: batch-file, echo

I have a settings.txt file that looks like this:

```
on
off
```

In the beginning of the batch file, various variable values are populated with these settings such as `%AutoTransfer%` being set to on, `AutoViewLog` set to on, etc.  Whenever one of these settings are toggled on/off, I call the `:WriteSettings` function which tries to do this:

```
echo %AutoTransfer% > settings.txt
echo %AutoViewLog% >> settings.txt
```

But instead the command interpreter turns echo itself on or off.  I've tried `!AutoTransfer!` and `(!AutoTransfer!)` still with no luck.  Of course I can change it to using enabled/disabled values instead of on/off values but that screws up my menu that relies on these words being short.  And if I resort to setting the values to be 1 for enabled and 0 for disabled, I have to write tons more code for the main menu (a bunch of "if" statements to echo "on" when the variable is 1, "off" when it is 0).

My current solution would work... it would assign values to "is on" instead of "on" and just make the word "is" part of the value of the variable so that I can use `'AutoTransfer %AutoTransfer%'` on the menu to display `"AutoTransfer is on"`.  But this feels like a duct tape solution, and for the pure virtue of learning, I want to know if there is an elegant solution to this or if all solutions are just as stupid/lame/ugly as that or possibly worse.

I also can't believe I seem to be the first to ask this question.  I looked for 20 minutes for anyone else who has asked this question... couldn't find a single one.  Am I really the first person who ever wanted to store/read/echo super basic "on/off" values to a settings file and to the screen?  Or am I just the first person who is too dumb to figure it out?

Comment: just avoid the cmd with legacy things and use powershell instead. It's easier to do everything in powershell

Comment: @phuclv: except that the powershell command would be something like `EchoTheString on -AppendToFile settings.txt -UseDefaultPermissions -UseEncoding utf-8 -BypassConversions -TwoTurtleDoves -AndAPartridgeInAPearTree` :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo except you just need `"on" > output` most of the time

Comment: @phuclv, I was just having a subtle dig at the verbosity of Powershell. I do like it however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of a non-space is the usual method for doing this, such as:

```
echo.on>>settings.txt
```

This prevents the `on` from being treated as a command to `echo` rather than a string to echo.

Note though that I have *no* space between the `on` and the output redirection there. If you put the space there, it's actually added to the file which is probably *not* what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set /P` to print

```
(
    set /P ="on" <nul
    echo(
    set /P ="off" <nul
    echo(
) > settings.txt
```

Alternatively [store the new line in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/132799/995714) and use it like this

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set \n=^
%=Do not remove this line=%
)

echo on!\n!off > settings.txt
```

You can also print directly using any combination to [print a blank line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20691061/995714)

```
echo(on
echo+on
echo,on
echo/on
echo;on
echo=on
echo[on
echo]on

echo(off
echo+off
echo,off
echo/off
echo;off
echo=off
echo[off
echo]off
```

although the fastest method is probably `echo(on` and the reliable ones might be `echo:on`, `echo\on` as indicated by the other answer

Comment: Clever stuff, thanks!  It was hard to pick which one was the "answer" to the question - the other answer was the simplest (and the solution I'm going with), but this answer was the most complete and stretched the heck out of my brain's 7 neurons.  Much appreciated!