# Send Commands to socket using netcat

Tags: shell, sockets, batch-file, tcp, netcat

I am sending text commands to a custom protocol TCP server. In the example below I send 2 commands and receive a response written back. It works as expected in telnet and netcat:

```
$ nc 192.168.1.186 9760
command1
command2
theresponse
```

not working when i tried in batch:

```
@echo off
cd..
cd C:\nc
nc 192.168.1.186 9760
00LI002LE99
end
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Please elaborate what "not working" means.  What do you see happen, and what do you expect to happen?  Put your commands in a file called "commands.txt" and then run `nc 192.168.1.186 9760 < "commands.txt"`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you run `nc` interactively, it takes input from standard input (your terminal), so you can interact with it and send your commands.

When you run it in your batch script, you need to feed the commands into the standard input stream of `nc` - just putting the commands on the following lines won't do that; it will try to run those as entirely separate batch commands.

You need to put your commands into a file, then redirect the file into `nc`:

```
nc 192.168.1.186 9760 < commands.txt
```

On Linux, you can use a "here document" to embed the commands in the script.

```
nc 192.168.1.186 9760 <<END
command1
command2
END
```

but I haven't found an equivalent for windows batch scripts. It's a bit ugly, but you could echo the commands to a temp file, then redirect that to `nc`:

```
echo command1^

command2 > commands.txt

nc 192.168.1.186 9760 < commands.txt
```

The `^` escape character enables you to put a literal newline into the script. Another way to get newlines into an echo command (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files)):

```
echo command1 & echo.command2 > commands.txt
```

Ideally we'd just pipe straight to `nc` (this isn't quite working for me, but I can't actually try it with `nc` at the moment):

```
echo command1 & echo.command2 | nc 192.168.1.186 9760
```

Comment: You may be able to use something like an echo tool with newlines on Windows to pipe a short multiline list into netcat.  It's also possible the destination system would accept the particular commands being used all on one line if separated with semicolons.

Comment: Have added a suggestion using a temp file - would be nice to do this with a pipe though. Good idea about semicolons.

Comment: I'd assumed so, but it's not working correctly for me (using `sort` command instead of `nc`, as I don't have `nc` installed on Windows), but will edit answer anyway...

Comment: Yes... windows seems to be broken (surprise!)  Sorry about that.