# New line char in file using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm making some test variable and I insert a new line character into it. When I print it everything is ok, 1 word is below the second one. But when I write the value of this variable into *.txt file the new line character doesn't work. 
Here is my example:

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(200), @var varchar(200)
SET @var = 'Hello' + CHAR(13) + 'world'

SET @cmd = 'echo ' + @var + ' > E:\s.txt'
print @cmd
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

I was trying with `DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` or `\r\n` instead of this `CHAR(13)` but no effect :/ Could someone give me small hint about this problem?
I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: You should probably get the syntax working [from a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files) first then pass the working syntax.

Comment: Try using another utility instead of echo. I reckon echo only read up to the newline char

Comment: Do you get HelloWorld in the text file or just Hello?

Comment: normally I got simple HeeloWorld, but using solution below I don't get anything, file isn't even created

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(200), @var varchar(200);
SET @var = 'Hello
world';

SET @cmd = 'echo ' + @var + ' > E:\s.txt';
print @cmd;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

EDIT:

I believe your problem is escaping the new line in the windows shell.  Try the escape character `'^'`:

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(200), @var varchar(200);
SET @var = 'Hello^
world';

SET @cmd = 'echo ' + @var + ' > E:\s.txt';
print @cmd;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Be sure there is no space or other character after the `'^'`.

Comment: No, it doesn't create any file then, normally result information is: output (newline) ----- (newline) NULL, but whene somethins is wrong like here there is ------ (newline) Hello (newline) NULL and no file is created

Comment: Still no difference - 'Hello^world' works, but making ENTER between '^' and 'world' doesn't work :/

Comment: @user3762819 . . . I'm out of ideas.  I'll leave this answer here in case it helps anyone else trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`How To add blank line in output/log/txt file`
`Sample Code`

`BEGIN`

`--Ebnable xp_cmdshell`
`EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;`
`RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;`
`EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;`
`RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;`

`DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(255);`
`DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';`
`DECLARE @v_MyOutFile_v VARCHAR(20)= 'C:\MyOutFile.txt'; --Provide output filename with path`

`--Add 1st line`
`SET @var = '1st Line';`
`SET @cmd = concat('echo ', @var, '>> "', @v_MyOutFile_v, '"');`
`exec xp_cmdshell @cmd,  no_output`

`--Add Blank line`
`SET @var = '& echo.'; --Blank line`
`SET @cmd = concat('echo ', @var, '>> "', @v_MyOutFile_v, '"'); --Do not add any spaces before >> otherwise it will be printed in the output file`
`exec xp_cmdshell @cmd,  no_output`

`--Add 2nd line after blank line`
`SET @var = '2nd Line';`
`SET @cmd = concat('echo ', @var, '>> "', @v_MyOutFile_v, '"');`
`exec xp_cmdshell @cmd,  no_output`

`--Disable xp_cmdshell`
`EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;`
`RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;`
`EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;`
`RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;`
`END;`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).