# Line break for two or more variables in batch

Tags: variables, batch-file

I have this piece of code:

```
echo %ip_address%>%logfile%
echo %hostname%>>%logfile%
echo %duration%>>%logfile%
```

However, I would like to know if it possible to echo each variable on a separate line.

I have tried the following:

```
 echo %ip_address% && %hostname% && %duration%>c:\text.txt
 echo %ip_address% & echo.%hostname% & echo.%duration%>c:\text.txt
```

None of these work.

Comment: Uhm, you're already writing them each on their own line ...

Comment: @Joey They are all going into the logfile and I wanted to know if you could echo with variables and <br>.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/269819/4158862

Comment: So the log file is a HTML file and you want to insert a `br` element?

Comment: @Joey No, not at all. It is a bat. I should has said new line.

Comment: Then it still makes absolutely no sense. `echo` *already writes only a single line*, which means that with three `echo` statements you get three lines.

Comment: @Joey I agree, however echo %ip_address% & echo.%hostname% & echo.%duration%>c:\text.txt' this should work, right?

Comment: Nope, it would print the value of `%ip_address%` and `%hostname%` to the screen, and only `%duration%` to the file. You need to use parentheses, if you want to redirect multiple commands at once