# Ruby multi-line backtick exec in Windows doesn't work

Tags: ruby, windows

This is what I'm doing:

```
cmd = "echo foo\n echo bar"
out = `#{cmd}`
```

In Linux I have "foo\nbar". In Windows I have "foo". Why is that? How to fix?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files

Answer (score 4):

It seems like `cmd.exe` read until the newline (`\n`) and ignore remaining part.

You can use `&&` instead to combine to commands:

```
cmd = "echo foo && echo bar"
out = `#{cmd}`
# => "foo \nbar\n"
```

Comment: ah, windows and its joke of a terminal :)