# Windows Echo Un-escaped backslash

Tags: windows, cmd, echo

I have this command:

```
echo PUT /123 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n | ncat 127.0.0.1 5000
```

which is returning HTTP 400, because echo is escaping the backslashes. I do not want the backslashes escaped because HTTP cannot understand that.

I tried:

- Enclosing in quotes (unfortunately echo prints those as well)
- Replacing \ with \\, \\\ and ^\

Neither seem to work. Seems like any time it sees a \, it adds another to it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-i-echo-a-newline-in-a-batch-file

Comment: That did it. Thanks! If you want to make that an answer to this question, I will upvote it and accept.

Comment: Glad that it was helpful. As I just googled it, I won't post it as an answer