# Removing carriage returns from a text file using a batch file based on a value

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have a text file that I would like to edit and therefore would like to remove the last line. I have the following code for this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
echo/|set /p ="%%a%"
)>>output.txt
```

input:

```
GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
```

output:

```
GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
```

Now I would like to edit the data in groups for example by the first value, so that I have the following output:

```
GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
```

Comment: ...based on _what_ value?

Comment: Sorry, the first value (GRUPPEA)

Comment: ...`SORT` based on _first_ value? your question remains unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I replace the `FOR /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do …` loop with an equivalent [`FOR %%a in …` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "_gruppeName="
(
  for %%a in (
    "GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;"
    "GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;"
    "GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;"
    "GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;"
    "GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;"
    "GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;"
    "GRUPPEC;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;"
    "GRUPPEC;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;"
    "GRUPPEC;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;"
  ) do (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=;" %%A in ("%%~a") do (
      if /I NOT "%%~A"=="!_gruppeName!" (
        if defined _gruppeName echo(
        set "_gruppeName=%%~A"
      )
    ) 
    echo/|set /p ="%%~a"
  )
  echo(
)>>output.txt
REM debugging output follows
type output.txt
```

**Output**:

**1st run**: `2>NUL del output.txt & D:\bat\CR\61816520.bat`

> ```
> GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
> GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
> GRUPPEC;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEC;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEC;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
> ```

**Next run**: `D:\bat\CR\61816520.bat`

> ```
> GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
> GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
> GRUPPEC;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEC;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEC;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
> GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEA;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
> GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEB;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
> GRUPPEC;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEC;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;GRUPPEC;123;12345;sdfdsfds;sdfdsfsdfs;sdfsdfafsf;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear

> based on ... the first value (GRUPPEA)

is it `SORT`ed? or just write duplicates on the same line?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

::VARIABLES
set "in=input.txt" IN file
set "out=output.txt" OUT file

set/a"#lines=0"
set "gruppe="
set "prevContent="

::Count lines
FOR /F %%L in ('
"findstr /N "^^" "%in%" %= do not skip empty lines =%"
') do set/a"#lines+=1" %= Get the # of lines =%


::Read IN via SET /P #LINES number of times
::Bangs (!) will be lost
<"%in%" >"%out%" (FOR /L %%# in (1 1 %#lines%) do (
    set "data="                           ::clear DATA
    set/p"data="                          ::read from IN
    FOR /F tokens^=1^ delims^=^;^ eol^= %%T in ("!data!") do set "gruppe=%%T"
    if NOT "!prevContent!" == "!gruppe!" (
        set "prevContent=!gruppe!"
        echo(
    )
    <nul set/p"=!data!"                    ::does not work with leading space, tabs, or equal signs
)) %= read file by lines via SET /P =%

exit /b
```

---

The script counts the number of lines using [`FINDSTR /N`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) and a [`FOR /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop to count the # of lines, which is required to execute `SET /P` that many times.

Tips:

- Use [`ECHO(`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379940/12861751) instead of the problematic `ECHO.`
- Using a pipe `|` is very slow, as described by **@jeb** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7105690/12861751). Use `<nul` instead