# How do I set the version information for an existing .exe, .dll?

Tags: windows, dll, versioning, exe, fileversioninfo

As part of our build process I need to set the version information for all of our compiled binaries. Some of the binaries already have version information (added at compile time) and some do not.

I want to be able to apply the following information:

- Company Name
- Copyright Notice
- Product Name
- Product Description
- File Version
- Product Version

All of these attributes are specified by the build script and must be applied after compilation. These are standard binaries (not assemblies) compiled with C++ Builder 2007.

How can I do this?

Comment: for what use *ResourceHacker* ? how exactly task is set ? in what problem use `UpdateResource` function, if task update version in existing pe

Comment: Try this: https://alternativeto.net/software/xn-resource-editor/ , I think there are reverse engineering tools do this

Answer (score 82):

While it's not a batch process, Visual Studio can also add/edit file resources.

Just use File->Open->File on the .EXE or .DLL.  This is handy for fixing version information post-build, or adding it to files that don't have these resources to begin with.

Comment: This worked perfectly when I tried it. For a file that is missing version info completely: After opening the DLL in Visual Studio, go to Edit > Add Resource > Version and click New. Then in the new Version tab, change FILEVERSION and PRODUCTVERSION, CompanyName, etc. Save the files and you're all set!

Comment: @UweBaemayr. the answer you quoted I want to ask on same as can we automate it as exactly I do the same post build and I want to automate it . But how ?

Comment: For my old Delphi win32 dll this does not work. Altough the dll information is correctly changed, when running sanity checks on it you realize it's corrupted.

Comment: Tried this (add version info) on Windows 8, VS 2015 and all is good in Windows Explorer, except ... the executable won't start anymore.

Comment: Using Visual Studio works with Visual Studio 2015, but not with 2019.

Comment: @Alenros It absolutely does work with VS 2019, at least for .exe files, which is what i worked with today.

Comment: You are right, it does work in 2019. I think I accidentally used Open Folder (ctrl-O) instead of Open File (ctrl-shift-O).

Comment: Corrupted my file in 2019

Comment: It works with VS 2022, so i see no reason it wouldn't work with 2019.

Answer (score 47):

Unlike many of the other answers, this solution uses completely free software.

Firstly, create a file called `Resources.rc` like this:

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
    FILEVERSION    1,0,0,0
    PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,0
{
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    {
        BLOCK "040904b0"
        {
            VALUE "CompanyName",        "ACME Inc.\0"
            VALUE "FileDescription",    "MyProg\0"
            VALUE "FileVersion",        "1.0.0.0\0"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",     "© 2013 ACME Inc. All Rights Reserved\0"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename",   "MyProg.exe\0"
            VALUE "ProductName",        "My Program\0"
            VALUE "ProductVersion",     "1.0.0.0\0"
        }
    }
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    {
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1200
    }
}
```

Next, use [GoRC](http://www.godevtool.com/) to compile it to a `.res` file using:

```
GoRC /fo Resources.res Resources.rc
```

<sup>(see my comment below for a mirror of `GoRC.exe`)</sup>

Then use [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) in CLI mode to add it to an existing `.exe`:

```
ResHacker -add MyProg.exe, MyProg.exe, Resources.res,,,
```

That's it!

Comment: @CharlesB I noticed that myself, but it's the right link. Looks like someone forgot to pay their web host! Here's the binary, I've mirrored it to my public Assembla account: https://www.assembla.com/code/danny-beckett/subversion/nodes/13/GoRC.exe

Comment: You can also use the Microsoft [Resource Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381042(v=vs.85).aspx) in place of GoRC. It's available with the Windows SDK.

Comment: Thumbs up for Resource Hacker, I used it based in this answer it and it is brilliant, great program. (no affinity with program or maker ;-)

Comment: @UweKeim I haven't used this for a while, but I'm pretty sure they're required.

Comment: Seems like command line has changed a bit: `ResourceHacker.exe -open Source.dll -save Changed.dll -action addoverwrite -resource Version.res` Also, ResourceHacker can compile .rc file itself: `ResourceHacker.exe -open Version.rc -save Version.res -action compile`

Answer (score 24):

Or you could check out the freeware [StampVer](http://blog.dixo.net/downloads/stampver/) for Win32 exe/dll files.
It will only change the file and product versions though if they have a version resource already. It cannot add a version resource if one doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 22):

**rcedit** is relative new and works well from the command line: https://github.com/atom/rcedit

```
$ rcedit "path-to-exe-or-dll" --set-version-string "Comments" "This is an exe"
$ rcedit "path-to-exe-or-dll" --set-file-version "10.7"
$ rcedit "path-to-exe-or-dll" --set-product-version "10.7"
```

There's also an [NPM module](https://github.com/atom/node-rcedit) which wraps it from JavaScript and a [Grunt task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-rcedit) in case you're using Grunt.

Comment: note that rcedit can only modify existing resources not insert new ones

Comment: Doesn't work with 7zip sfx archives :/ Just cuts out the 7zip archive part.

Comment: tried this, keeps giving unable to load file when in the same directory and seems like the tool may depend on host configuration

Comment: Works with the 7zS.sfx stub, the first part with the VERSIONINFO inside that you use to concat together a self extracting archive. Manually you can also rename 7zS.sfx in 7zS.exe and edit it in Visual Studio but since the version number is changing for every build you prefer a batch file with rcedit statements inside to set it.

Comment: this tool is very nasty, please look at this bug before applying it onto your binaries: https://github.com/electron/rcedit/issues/51

Comment: Corrupted my binary.

Answer (score 16):

There are multiple tools, mentioned by many great answers, I'm going to pick one.

## *Resource Hacker*

I downloaded latest version (*5.1.7*) from [[AngusJ]: Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker). All the needed information can be found on that page (command line options, scripts, ...). In the following walkthrough I'm going to operate on 2 executables (lab rats) which (for obvious reasons) I've copied in my *cwd*:

- *ResourceHacker.exe*: I thought it would be interesting to operate on itself
- *cmake.exe*: random executable with no *Version Info* set (part of *v3.6.3* installation on my machine)

Before going further, I want to mention that ***ResourceHacker* has a funny terminal output**, and the the following copy / paste fragments might generate a bit of confusion.

### 1. Setup

This is more like a preliminary step, to get acquainted with the environment, to show there's no funky business going on, ...

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> dir
>  Volume in drive E is Work
>  Volume Serial Number is 3655-6FED
>
>  Directory of e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258
>
> 2019-01-28  20:09    <DIR>          .
> 2019-01-28  20:09    <DIR>          ..
> 2016-11-03  09:17         5,413,376 cmake.exe
> 2019-01-03  02:06         5,479,424 ResourceHacker.exe
> 2019-01-28  20:30               496 ResourceHacker.ini
>                3 File(s)     10,893,296 bytes
>                2 Dir(s)  103,723,261,952 bytes free
>
> [prompt]> set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Install\x64\CMake\CMake\3.6.3\bin
>
> [prompt]> .\cmake --help >nul 2>&1
>
> [prompt]> echo %errorlevel%
> 0
>
> [prompt]> .\ResourceHacker.exe -help
>
> [prompt]>
>
> ==================================
> Resource Hacker Command Line Help:
> ==================================
>
> -help             : displays these abbreviated help instructions.
> -help commandline : displays help for single commandline instructions
> -help script      : displays help for script file instructions.
>
>
>
>
> [prompt]> echo %errorlevel%
> 0
> ```

As seen, the executables are OK, they run fine, and here's how their *Details* (that we care about) look like:

[image: Img0-Initial]

### 2. Resources

Resource files are text files that contain resources. A resource (simplified) has:

- Name
- Type
- Value

For more details check [[MS.Docs]: About Resource Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/about-resource-files). There are many tools (mentioned in existing answers) that facilitate resource file editing like:

- *VStudio* creates a default one when starting a new project
- One can create such a file manually
- But, since it's about *Resource Hacker*, and:

  - It is able to extract resources from an existing executable
  - It has resources embedded in it (as shown in the previous picture)

  I'm going to use it for this step (`-action extract`)

Next, In order for a resource to be embedded into an *.exe* (*.dll*, ...) it must be *compiled* to a binary form, which fits into the *PE* format. Again, there are lots of tools who can achieve this, but as you probably guessed I'm going to stick to *Resource Hacker* (`-action compile`).

> ```bat
> [prompt]> :: Extract the resources into a file
> [prompt]> .\ResourceHacker.exe -open .\ResourceHacker.exe -save .\sample.rc -action extract -mask VersionInfo,, -log con
>
> [prompt]>
>
> [28 Jan 2019, 20:58:03]
>
> Current Directory:
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258
>
> Commandline:
> .\ResourceHacker.exe  -open .\ResourceHacker.exe -save .\sample.rc -action extract -mask VersionInfo,, -log con
>
> Open    : e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258\ResourceHacker.exe
> Save    : e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258\sample.rc
>
>
> Success!
>
> [prompt]> :: Modify the resource file and set our own values
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Compile the resource file
> [prompt]> .\ResourceHacker.exe -open .\sample.rc -save .\sample.res -action compile -log con
>
> [prompt]>
>
> [28 Jan 2019, 20:59:51]
>
> Current Directory:
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258
>
> Commandline:
> .\ResourceHacker.exe  -open .\sample.rc -save .\sample.res -action compile -log con
>
> Open    : e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258\sample.rc
> Save    : e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258\sample.res
>
> Compiling: e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258\sample.rc
> Success!
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> cmake.exe
> ResourceHacker.exe
> ResourceHacker.ini
> sample.rc
> sample.res
> ```

In your case saving and editing the resource file won't be necessary, as the file will already be present, I just did it for demonstrating purposes. Below it's the resource file after being modified (and thus before being compiled).

*sample.rc*:

```rc
1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 3,1,4,1592
PRODUCTVERSION 2,7,1,8
FILEOS 0x4
FILETYPE 0x1
{
BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
{
    BLOCK "040904E4"
    {
        VALUE "CompanyName", "Cristi Fati\0"
        VALUE "FileDescription", "20190128 - SO q000284258 demo\0"
        VALUE "FileVersion", "3.1.4.1592\0"
        VALUE "ProductName", "Colonel Panic\0"
        VALUE "InternalName", "100\0"
        VALUE "LegalCopyright", "(c) Cristi Fati 1999-2999\0"
        VALUE "OriginalFilename", "ResHack\0"
        VALUE "ProductVersion", "2.7.1.8\0"
    }
}

BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
{
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0409 0x04E4  
}
}
```

### 3. Embed

This will also be performed by *Resource Hacker* (`-action addoverwrite`). Since the *.exe*s are already copied I'm going to edit their resources in place.

> ```bat
> [prompt]> .\ResourceHacker.exe -open .\cmake.exe -save .\cmake.exe -res .\sample.res -action addoverwrite -mask VersionInfo,, -log con
>
> [prompt]>
>
> [28 Jan 2019, 21:17:19]
>
> Current Directory:
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258
>
> Commandline:
> .\ResourceHacker.exe  -open .\cmake.exe -save .\cmake.exe -res .\sample.res -action addoverwrite -mask VersionInfo,, -log con
>
> Open    : e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258\cmake.exe
> Save    : e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258\cmake.exe
> Resource: e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258\sample.res
>
>   Added: VERSIONINFO,1,1033
>
> Success!
>
> [prompt]> copy ResourceHacker.exe ResourceHackerTemp.exe
>         1 file(s) copied.
>
> [prompt]> .\ResourceHackerTemp.exe -open .\ResourceHacker.exe -save .\ResourceHacker.exe -res .\sample.res -action addoverwrite -mask VersionInfo,, -log con
>
> [prompt]>
>
> [28 Jan 2019, 21:19:29]
>
> Current Directory:
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258
>
> Commandline:
> .\ResourceHackerTemp.exe  -open .\ResourceHacker.exe -save .\ResourceHacker.exe -res .\sample.res -action addoverwrite -mask VersionInfo,, -log con
>
> Open    : e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258\ResourceHacker.exe
> Save    : e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258\ResourceHacker.exe
> Resource: e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258\sample.res
>
>   Modified: VERSIONINFO,1,1033
>
> Success!
>
> [prompt]> del /f /q ResourceHackerTemp.*
>
> [prompt]> dir
>  Volume in drive E is Work
>  Volume Serial Number is 3655-6FED
>
>  Directory of e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q000284258
>
> 2019-01-28  21:20    <DIR>          .
> 2019-01-28  21:20    <DIR>          ..
> 2016-11-03  09:17         5,414,400 cmake.exe
> 2019-01-03  02:06         5,479,424 ResourceHacker.exe
> 2019-01-28  21:17               551 ResourceHacker.ini
> 2019-01-28  20:05             1,156 sample.rc
> 2019-01-28  20:59               792 sample.res
>                5 File(s)     10,896,323 bytes
>                2 Dir(s)  103,723,253,760 bytes free
> ```

As seen, I had to d a little trick (*gainarie*) as I can't (at least I don't think I can) modify the *.exe* while in use.

### 4. Test

This is an optional phase, to make sure that:

- The executables still work (they weren't messed up in the process)
- The resources have been added / updated

> ```bat
> [prompt]> .\cmake --help >nul 2>&1
>
> [prompt]> echo %errorlevel%
> 0
>
> [prompt]> .\ResourceHacker.exe -help
>
> [prompt]>
>
> ==================================
> Resource Hacker Command Line Help:
> ==================================
>
> -help             : displays these abbreviated help instructions.
> -help commandline : displays help for single commandline instructions
> -help script      : displays help for script file instructions.
>
>
>
>
> [prompt]> echo %errorlevel%
> 0
> ```

And their *Details*:

[image: Img1-Final]

Comment: Very nice answer. Unfortunately ResourceHacker is no longer maintained and runs out of memory when trying to edit a large EXE file (I got the error trying to open a 3GB exe).

Comment: @LewsTherin: The latest version (also used by the answer) is from 2019/01, so I'd say it's pretty maintained. The problem is that it's *32bit*. You could contact the authors asking for a *64bit* version (I assume that since they already have the code it wouldn't be hard to build it for *64bit*).

Comment: @LewsTherin  just out of curiosity, how did you end up with a 3gb executable?  A game where all assets are embedded as resources (which are slow to load)?

Comment: @Lothar At the time I was working on localizing an EXE from a custom-built C++ application.

Answer (score 15):

What about something like this?

```
verpatch /va foodll.dll %VERSION% %FILEDESCR% %COMPINFO% %PRODINFO% %BUILDINFO%
```

Available [here with full sources](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/VerPatch.aspx?msg=3207401).

Comment: Verpatch seemed to create a bad product version resource for me (using the `/va /pv` option). The version appeared correctly in Windows Explorer but the last character was missing when retrieved in code with `VerQueryValue`. 

To fix the bad resource, I did this: (1) Load the DLL in Resource Hacker. (2) View the version resource. (3) Compile (modify something then change it back to enable the button). (4) Save.

Comment: verpatch works great for both x64 and x86 version of my DLLs on my dev box however in apveyor build project it only works for x64 and it is not doing absolutely nothing to the x86 dll -- no error either! any hints what might happen?
I can see in appveyor log the verpatch command is executing, no errors, and the dll is not getting somehow replaced and the end it is not having the version stamp; 
for x64 everything works fine on all situations.
any clues please?

Comment: @Ovi-Wan Kenobi : I didn't know what apveyor was, but according to your description, it looks to me more like an apveyor problem. At worst, if that's possible, get ready for some debugging in the apveyor environment?...

Answer (score 12):

I'm doing it with no additional tool. I have just added the following files to my Win32 app project.

One header file which defines some constants than we can reuse on our resource file and even on the program code. We only need to maintain one file.
Thanks to the Qt team that showed me how to do it on a Qt project, it now also works on my Win32 app.

----[version.h]----

```
#ifndef VERSION_H
#define VERSION_H

#define VER_FILEVERSION             0,3,0,0
#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "0.3.0.0\0"

#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION          0,3,0,0
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR      "0.3.0.0\0"

#define VER_COMPANYNAME_STR         "IPanera"
#define VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR     "Localiza archivos duplicados"
#define VER_INTERNALNAME_STR        "MyProject"
#define VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR      "Copyright 2016 ipanera@gmail.com"
#define VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR    "All Rights Reserved"
#define VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS2_STR    VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR
#define VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR    "MyProject.exe"
#define VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR         "My project"

#define VER_COMPANYDOMAIN_STR       "www.myurl.com"

#endif // VERSION_H
```

----[MyProjectVersion.rc]----

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "version.h"

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     VER_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION  VER_PRODUCTVERSION
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904E4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName",        VER_COMPANYNAME_STR
            VALUE "FileDescription",    VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR
            VALUE "FileVersion",        VER_FILEVERSION_STR
            VALUE "InternalName",       VER_INTERNALNAME_STR
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",     VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks1",   VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS1_STR
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks2",   VER_LEGALTRADEMARKS2_STR
            VALUE "OriginalFilename",   VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductName",        VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductVersion",     VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR
        END
    END

    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252
    END
END
```

Comment: Just curious; how did you stop windows from overwriting your .rc file every time you change a dialog or modify any resource in the project?  I've seen a couple of articles like this so far and it seems like it would work if you never have to change a resource again that would cause auto generation by the IDE.

Comment: @shawn1874 -- Include the line `#include <windows.h>` in the `resource.h` file that's added automatically. That file isn't regenerated (note at the top of the .rc file it indicates it's generated code, and can be modified in the designer).

Comment: @CJBS that doesn't answer the question.  Although that might work, it doesn't explain how the posted answer might work.  In the posted answer user3016543 is including the version.h directly within the .rc file.  There are several ways to deal with the overwrite of the .rc file which I know how to do.  I'm only questioning the way that this particular answer is shown because it does not look right to me.

Comment: I'm guessing that method works for him because the component in question doesn't have dialog components so the file doesn't get regenerated often or ever.  However in a windows application with MFC dialog resources that would not be the case.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of a technique that I first saw in action in a resource file that shipped with the WinBatch Extender SDK. It had been so long since I've needed it that I had forgotten most of the details. Your explanation brought it all back.

Answer (score 11):

There is this tool [ChangeVersion](http://www.the-software-box.com/changeversion.aspx) <sup>[1]</sup>

List of features (from the website):

> - command line interface
> - support for .EXE, .DLL and .RES files
> - update FileVersion and ProductVersion based on a version mask
> - add/change/remove version key strings
> - adjust file flags (debug, special, private etc)
> - update project files ( .bdsproj | .bpr | .bpk | .dproj )
> - add/change main application icon
> - use ini file with configuration
> - Windows Vista support (needs elevation)
> - easy to integrate into a continuous build environment

Full Disclosure: I know the guy who wrote this tool, I used to work with him.  But this also means that I know he makes quality software ;)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> the link is dead. There seems to be mirrored version at [download.cnet.com](http://download.cnet.com/ChangeVersion/3000-2383_4-75765045.html).

Comment: @Gareth I added a mirror link. Otherside, I doubt that this answer has any value without any working reference.

Comment: The second link results in an expired tool `"Change Version v2012.9.6.0 - (C)2007-2012 The-Software-Box.com

This trial version has expired"`

Comment: When running it in command line, it says "Change Version v2012.9.6.0 - (C)2007-2012 The-Software-Box.com
This trial version has expired"

Answer (score 9):

verpatch is good, but doesn't handle unicode characters...
try [ResourceLib](https://github.com/dblock/resourcelib)

Answer (score 6):

the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839527/12327655) answer  from @DannyBeckett helped me a lot,

I put the following in a batch file & I place it in the same folder where ResourceHacker.exe & the EXE I work on is located & it works excellent.
[you may edit it to fit your needs]

```
    @echo off
    :start1
    set /p newVersion=Enter version number [?.?.?.?]:
    if "%newVersion%" == "" goto start1
    :start2
    set /p file=Enter EXE name [for 'program.exe' enter 'program']:
    if "%file%" == "" goto start2
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ('echo %newVersion%') do (set ResVersion=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d)
    (
    echo:VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
    echo:    FILEVERSION    %ResVersion%
    echo:    PRODUCTVERSION %ResVersion%
    echo:{
    echo:    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    echo:    {
    echo:        BLOCK "040904b0"
    echo:        {
    echo:            VALUE "CompanyName",        "MyCompany\0"
    echo:            VALUE "FileDescription",    "TestFile\0"
    echo:            VALUE "FileVersion",        "%newVersion%\0"
    echo:            VALUE "LegalCopyright",     "COPYRIGHT © 2019 MyCompany\0"
    echo:            VALUE "OriginalFilename",   "%file%.exe\0"
    echo:            VALUE "ProductName",        "Test\0"
    echo:            VALUE "ProductVersion",     "%newVersion%\0"
    echo:        }
    echo:    }
    echo:    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    echo:    {
    echo:        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1200
    echo:    }
    echo:}
    ) >Resources.rc     &&      echo setting Resources.rc
    ResourceHacker.exe -open resources.rc -save resources.res -action compile -log CONSOLE
    ResourceHacker -open "%file%.exe" -save "%file%Res.exe" -action addoverwrite -resource "resources.res"  -log CONSOLE
    ResourceHacker.exe -open "%file%Res.exe" -save "%file%Ico.exe" -action addskip -res "%file%.ico" -mask ICONGROUP,MAINICON, -log CONSOLE
    xCopy /y /f "%file%Ico.exe" "%file%.exe"
    echo.
    echo.
    echo your compiled file %file%.exe is ready
    pause
```

[as a side note i used resource hacker also to compile the res file, not GoRC]

Answer (score 5):

I want to put together a more compact version

- Step 1: create resource
- Step 2: Download ResourceHacker
- Step 3: Compile res into rc files
- Step 4: Run script: modify exe

#### Step 1: create `resource`

Prepare the resource file: `resource.rc`

```json
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
    FILEVERSION    0,0,0,0
    PRODUCTVERSION 0,0,0,0
{
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    {
        BLOCK "040904b0"
        {
            VALUE "CompanyName",        "\0"
            VALUE "FileDescription",    "\0"
            VALUE "FileVersion",        "0.0.0.0\0"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",     "© 2020 Carson. All rights reserved.\0"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename",   ".exe\0"
            VALUE "ProductName",        "\0"
            VALUE "ProductVersion",     "0.0.0.0\0"
        }
    }
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    {
        VALUE "Translation", 0x0409, 1200
    }
}
```

- [VSVersionInfo Fileds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997.aspx)
- [VarFileInfo: query langID and charsetID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/varfileinfo-block)

#### Step 2: Download ResourceHacker

There have two methods that can get it.

1. Download from [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/):

   - [install choco](https://chocolatey.org/install)
   - `choco install reshack -y`
   - After installation, you may need to add environment variables.
2. [ResourceHacker Website](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)

#### Step 3: Compile `res` into `rc` files

```
ResourceHacker.exe -open resources.rc -save resources.res ^
 -action compile -log CONSOLE
```

#### Step 4: Run script: modify exe

```
SET INPUT_EXE=app.exe
SET OUTPUT_EXE=app.exe
ResourceHacker.exe -open %OUTPUT_EXE% -save %OUTPUT_EXE% ^
 -resource resources.res ^
 -action addoverwrite ^
 -mask VersionInf ^
 -log CONSOLE
```

#### Summary Script

```
SET INPUT_EXE=app.exe
SET OUTPUT_EXE=app.exe

ResourceHacker.exe -open resources.rc -save resources.res ^
 -action compile -log CONSOLE

ResourceHacker.exe -open %OUTPUT_EXE% -save %OUTPUT_EXE% ^
 -resource resources.res ^
 -action addoverwrite ^
 -mask VersionInf ^
 -log CONSOLE
```

#### Reference

- [⭐resourcehacker Command Line Syntax](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) open and search: `Command Line Syntax`
  (*I strongly recommend that you take a look*)
- [Split long commands in multiple lines through Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69079) : `^`

Answer (score 4):

A little late to the party, but since I was looking for it (and I might need to find it again sometime), here's what I did to include version, company name, etc. into my C++ DLL under VS2013 Express:

1. Created and edited a dllproj.rc file, as indicated previously.
2. Added the line "rc.exe dllproj.rc" as a pre-build step in the DLL
   project.
3. Added dllproj.res to the resource folder for the project.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

There is **[Resource Tuner Console](http://www.heaventools.com/command-line_resource_editor.htm)** from Heaventools Software.

> Resource Tuner Console is a command-line tool that enables developers to automate editing of different resource types in large numbers of Windows 32- and 64-bit executable files.

See specifically the [Changing Version Variables And Updating The Version Information](http://www.heaventools.com/rtconsole-sample-script-update-version-info.htm) page for greater details.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually try downloading **FVIE** from [Download Link](https://www.carifred.com/fvie/) and try editing the information for any .exe file.

*(OR)*

You can download **StampVer – Win32 Version Resource Stamping** from [Download Link](http://blog.dixo.net/downloads/stampver/)
 which is really usefull for windows .exe files.

*(OR)*

You could use a command tool called **RCEDIT**. Download from [Github Source link](https://github.com/electron/rcedit) and then build using Visual Studio 2015 and then you have specific commands to change the version of .exe files. See [Docs link](https://github.com/electron/rcedit#docs) for various available commands.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best tool I've seen for the job, allows full control over all file resources, VersionInfo included.

See: [ResourceEditor](http://melander.dk/reseditor/) by [Anders Melander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2249664/speedfreak).

Comment: The download for Resource Editor (0 bytes) is broken.