# How do I change an EXE or DLL version number from the command line?

Tags: vb6, build-automation, versioning

I need to build an old VB6 application with a version number where the 4th digit is greater than 9999, for example, version `1.2.0.10003`.  VB6 won't let you do this; the build fails.

The current workaround is to build version `1.2.0.9999` and then manually edit the file in Visual Studio to insert the correct version.  There must be a better way.  Is there a command-line tool that allows you to modify the version number fields of an EXE or DLL?  Preferably a way that allows you to edit specific version number fields individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>There are a number of tools for editing the version info of a windows executable but I don't think you will need them.</strike>

Look here are using resource files in vb
http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usevb6/a/ResVB6.htm

And here for info on the version resource
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058.aspx

And here for info on the microsoft resource compiler
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381042(VS.85).aspx

With these two you should be able to disable VB's builtin versioning and use whatever version info you want.

Nevermind, VB6 inserts its own version resource as a post build operation with no way to turn it off. Overwriting the version info in the executable is the only solution.

See http://www.darinhiggins.com/?s=%22resource+files%22

Comment: Your answer lead me to the tool http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/ that did the job for me as a GUI tool.

Answer (score 2):

[ChangeVersion](http://www.the-software-box.com/changeversion.aspx) (and others) taken from:

[How do I set the version information for an existing .exe, .dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284258/how-do-i-set-the-version-information-for-an-existing-exe-dll)

Comment: It would be nice to find a free tool - call me a cheapskate if you like

Comment: It can't be that hard to write - just a resource editor with a GUI for version numbering.  But, given the cost of the tool and the amount of time to spend on writing your own, it's probably worth it...  I'll look for a free one.

Answer (score 1):

**[Resource Tuner Console](http://www.heaventools.com/command-line_resource_editor.htm)**

> This console resource editor allows creating a reliable and repeatable
>   process for updating Product Version Information resources during the final
>   stage of the build process from the command prompt.

See specifically the **batch manipulation of file version information** page for greater details:

- http://www.heaventools.com/rtconsole-update-version-info.htm

Answer (score 1):

[StampVer](http://www.elphin.com/downloads/stampver/)

Answer (score 0):

I think `editbin` might be a better solution (installed with Visual Studio)