# How do you combine .rc with .cpp files to form .exe?

Tags: c++, windows, linker, g++, rc

I have been trying to figure out, for a while now, how to set the Description, when looking in Task Manager, when compiling from the command prompt using g++. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022449/how-to-change-an-executables-properties-windows) resource example but when I run `windres foo.rc foores.o`, `g++ -c foo.cpp`, `g++ -o foo.exe foo.o foores.o` and then look at Task Manager I still see foo.exe in the Description field.

I have found many sites and examples but nothing that I have tried seems to work. Any help would be appreciated. I prefer not to use Visual Studio.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708238/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-a-mingw-gcc-compiled-executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Martin Beckett said is absolutely correct. The answer to this question is there but you have to go to the big gray box in the answer.  Also, for people who are too lazy to click on the link, here is the exact code.

```
1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     1,0,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION  1,0,0,0
BEGIN
  BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    BLOCK "080904E4"
    BEGIN
      VALUE "CompanyName", "My Company Name"
      VALUE "FileDescription", "My excellent application"
      VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0"
      VALUE "InternalName", "my_app"
      VALUE "LegalCopyright", "My Name"
      VALUE "OriginalFilename", "my_app.exe"
      VALUE "ProductName", "My App"
      VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0"
    END
  END

  BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    VALUE "Translation", 0x809, 1252
  END
END
```

To Compile use

```
windres my.rc myres.o
g++ -c app.cpp -o app.o
g++ myres.o app.o -o app.exe
```