# Tooltip on application deployed through JavaFX Deployment

Tags: deployment, javafx-2, javafx

I have deployed a swing application with JavaFX deployment. I want to set a tooltip On Application exe. Tooltip will consist of my application name, Version and other description. But I don't have idea about how to set tool tip on javaFx deployed exe.

Please suggest me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add tooltip to exe file by JavaFX tools. Executable files, their properties and tooltips are handled by system means.

In case of Windows you can update file properties using exe resource editors. There properties will be visible on Details page and some of them are shown in tooltip depending on Windows version.

In next question there are several link to resource editors: [How to change an executable's properties? (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022449/how-to-change-an-executables-properties-windows)