# Change icon of exe in c

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, icons, mingw, exe

I've a problem here . When I compiled a .exe file, the default icon of the application will be the windows console icon(like cmd.exe one). Is there any method I can change the icon to my custom icon??

I am using vscode and MinGW C compiler.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a resource file to your project and define an icon there. The first icon will be used as the application icon by Explorer. The icons are sorted by their order and alphabetically, so you should give it a name that ensures that it is the first one.

```
AA_MYAPPICON ICON "sample.ico"
```

Comment: can you explain how to add resource file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508242/how-to-compile-resource-file-with-mingw-windres

Comment: Yeah.. Thank You ! Its Working