# How can the default language property be set for an executable with visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, localization

I would like to set the language property for my executable, but I am unable to do so with visual studio.

So as I checked in another exe's property I can see this:

[image]

On the other hand, in my executable compiled with visual studio the language parameter is empty.

How can it be set?

Edit:
Also, would it affect the character encoding?

Comment: [exe properteries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022449/how-to-change-an-executables-properties-windows), hope this helps. Also the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change an executable's properties? (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022449/how-to-change-an-executables-properties-windows)

Comment: @Fade Thanks. It was helpful. Also, if the language property is set would it affect the character encoding?

Comment: according to the documentation you can set the encoding seperately. See the parameter `charsetID` under the `langID` parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in PROJECT | Properties -> Resource -> Culture. It will affect the character encoding. You may have to save your .rc file encoding to Unicode.