# How can I embed a version into a DLL?

Tags: dll, ant, version, embed

I have a project that is mainly Java, but also uses some C, which is built into a DLL, using ant for the whole build. I want to add versioning, so that the same version is embedded in the jar files, and also in the dll files. For the jars it was simple, but how can I do this for the dlls?

I know you can embed different resources like a manifest using mt.exe, but I'm not sure how to do this with a version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:  [How do I set the version information for an existing .exe, .dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284258/how-do-i-set-the-version-information-for-an-existing-exe-dll)

Comment: Thanks! That stampver tool is exactly what I needed.